# Why does Evaluate[a[[1]]]=0 assign a value to a variable while a[[1]]=0 doesn't?

Tags: evaluation, variable-definitions

I'm trying to do a small page counter with Mathematica, for leting me know about my reading progress on some books. I'm stuck on a problem:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a = {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6}
a[[1]] = 0
v1
```

With this, I'm trying to give 0 as a value to v1, but it seems that it swaps the v1 for 0 instead. I was expecting the evaluation of v1 to give me 0 as a value, but it still gives me v1, I've managed to partialy solve this with the following addition:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a = {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6}
Evaluate[a[[1]]] = 0
v1
```

When the v1 is evaluated, it gives me 0 as output, but it's not working in my program and I have no idea why this is happening.

I've also managed to perform a separate test by evaluation both:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a = {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6}
Evaluate[a[[1]]] = 0
v1

Clear["Global`*"]
a = {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6}
a[[1]] = 0
v1
```

In this case, it the outputs for both v1's are v1. Why is this happening?

> My program(If needed):
>
> ```
> Clear["Global`*"]
> g = 1; i = 1; l = {}; ln = {}; pi = {}; m = 1;
> r1 := AppendTo[l, ToExpression["p" <> ToString[i++]]]
> r2 := AppendTo[ln, n]
> r3 := Clear[n]
> r4 := AppendTo[pi, np] 
> r5 := Clear[np]
> r6 := Evaluate[l[[m]]] = 0 
> r7 := m++
>
> o1 = Button["+1", r1; r2; r3; r4; r5; r6; r7, ImageSize -> {30, 19}];
> o2 = InputField[Dynamic[n], String, FieldSize -> {15, 1}];
> o3 = InputField[Dynamic[np], Number, FieldSize -> {4, 1}];
> o4 = {o1, o2, o3};
> o5 = Style["Book", 12];
> o6 = Style["Book Title", 12];
> o7 = Style["# Pages", 12];
> o8 = {o5, o6, o7};
>
> Grid[{o8, o4}, Frame -> True]
>
> t = Table[Button[ToString[x], Delete[l, {x}]], {x, 1, Length[l]}] // 
>   Dynamic
> l // Dynamic
> ln // Dynamic
> pi // Dynamic
> ```

Comment: Your "failing test" performs as expected here. (Mma 8.0, Win)

Comment: I'm on 8.0 Win too.

Answer (score 6):

It is because `a[[1]]` does not evaluate to `v1` in the case of assignment `a[[1]] = 0` because `Set` (`=`) has attribute `HoldFirst`:

```
In[1]:= Set // Attributes

Out[1]= {HoldFirst, Protected, SequenceHold}
```

So you just [reassign the first element of the list](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html#20454) `a` to `0`:

```
In[6]:= Clear["Global`*"]
a = {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6};
a[[1]] = 0;
a

Out[9]= {0, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6}
```

In the case of assignment `Evaluate[a[[1]]] = 0` you override this attribute and assign to the variable `v1` (if it is undefined).

The third piece of code in your question works as expected on my machine:

```
In[13]:= Clear["Global`*"]
a = {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6};
Evaluate[a[[1]]] = 0;
v1

Clear["Global`*"]
a = {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6};
a[[1]] = 0;
v1

Out[16]= 0

Out[20]= v1
```

P.S. You may be interested in this discussion: "[Elegant manipulation of the variables list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322/280)."

Comment: Did you see it doesn't work in the program? I have no idea why it's not working there. Did you test this solution with the entire program?

Comment: @GustavoBandeira I tried your program, but I was not able to understand what is the expected result

Comment: @GustavoBandeira Your test code works as expected, see updated answer.

Comment: @belisarius It's still not ready. I want to do a table with `ProgressIndicators` and a `+` button to increment the page by one.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira As to your program, you may start debugging it with replacement of the first `Dynamic` with `Table[With[{x = x}, Button[ToString[x], l = Delete[l, {x}]]], {x, 1, 
   Length[l]}] // Dynamic`. I should note that the overall design is not clear and not very *Mathematica* and instead of debugging I would rewrite this program in more *Mathematica*-style from scratch.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov It's not working here. When I press the `+ Book` Button, it adds a book in the reading list, but trying to call the v1 variable still gives me a variable with no value.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira Your test example with the `v1` variable works as expected as I showed in the answer. Does not it work for you? My suggestion in the last comment is not a solution - just a place to start. I just tried to correct the most obvious mistakes in your code.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Oh, when I posted my [comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17542/why-does-evaluatea1-0-assign-a-value-to-a-variable-while-a1-0-doesnt/17549#comment51880_17543), your [comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17542/why-does-evaluatea1-0-assign-a-value-to-a-variable-while-a1-0-doesnt/17549#comment51879_17543) wasn't shown here, slow internet. =/

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Assigning values to a list of variable names](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6511/121), my answer to it, and the four linked questions in the comment below the question.  There you will find a better alternative (indexed variables) *and* a way to work with a list of symbols should you insist.

A brief example:

```
assign[symbols_, idx_, val_] := symbols[[{idx}]] /. _[x_] :> (x = val)

a = Hold[v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6];

assign[a, 1, 0];

v1
```

> ```
> 0
> ```