# why set values in this way doesn't work?

Tags: programming, assignment

question is as follows

define a list

```
ttt={1,2};
```

and if I set values in this way

```
{ttt[[1]],ttt[[2]]}={3,4}
```

then the value of list ttt now becomes {3,4}

Now I try this

```
f:={ttt[[1]],ttt[[2]]}
```

then `?f` will show that `f:={tmp[[1]],tmp[[2]]}`

then if I just write

```
f={3,4}
```

this will not affect the values of list ttt .

**the question is that I want the values of list ttt changes as well when I set values to f. How to do this?**

---

**More Question!!**

why the following code didn't change the value of ttt??

```
Table[With[{i = i}, Defer@ttt[[i]]], {i, 1, 2}] = {111, 222}
```

while

```
Table[With[{i = i}, Defer@ttt[[i]]], {i, 1, 2}]
```

really gives

```
{ttt[[1]],ttt[[2]]}
```

Comment: The assignment to list part (`ttt[[3]]=val`) only works, if the list part is at the left hand side of the `Set` operator (as `Set` has attribute `HoldFirst`), otherwise it simply returns the appropriate element of `ttt`.

Comment: You can make `ttt` change when `f` changes by using `SetDelayed`, as in `ttt:=f`. But it sounds like you are trying to do this at the same time as you set `f:=ttt`. You can't do both at once because it creates a circle (you will get a recursion error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would approach this by combining the functionality of `bump` given in:
[Elegant manipulation of the variables list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10322/elegant-manipulation-of-the-variables-list/17553#17553)
 with my `step` evaluation function described here:
[How do I evaluate only one step of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/334/how-do-i-evaluate-only-one-step-of-an-expression/1447#1447)

The `step` function is needed to (easily) recover the expression `{ttt[[1]], ttt[[2]]}` from the definition of `f` without it fully evaluating.  It can be used like this, with the [injector pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/121):

```
ttt = {1, 2};
f := {ttt[[1]], ttt[[2]]}

step[f] /. _[x_] :> (x = {3, 4})

ttt
```

> ```
> {3, 4}
> ```

To make this more convenient, and to work with other functions (see the first question linked above for examples) I would then write (after loading [`step`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/334/how-do-i-evaluate-only-one-step-of-an-expression/1447#1447)):

```
func_[boost[expr_], arg___] ^:= step[expr] /. _[x_] :> func[x, arg]
```

Example of use:

```
boost[f] = {5, 6};

ttt
```

> ```
> {5, 6}
> ```

Comment: This is very cool. +1

Comment: @Simon Thank you. :-)  I have yet to find as nice a way to approach something like this as to use `step`; I find a lot of use for that function since writing it.  Out of curiosity, are you using it for anything?

Comment: No, but I will in future! I must have seen it before, as I'd already upvoted the question and answer, but I'd forgotten about it. Stupid memory...

Comment: @Simon How I feel about my own memory: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClgLvztrXbk

Answer (score 3):

You may use `ReleaseHold[Hold[f = {3, 4}] /. OwnValues[f]]` :

```
ttt = {1, 2};
f := {ttt[[1]], ttt[[2]]};

ReleaseHold[Hold[f = {3, 4}] /. OwnValues[f]]

?ttt

(* ttt -> {3,4} *)
```

Some explanations :

- The fullform of `f={3,4}` is `Set[f, List[3, 4]]`.
- `Set` has attribute Holdfirst.
- We want to transform `Set[f, List[3, 4]]` in `{ttt[[1]], ttt[[2]]}={3,4}`.

So :
-`f` must be evaluated, that is to say  f must become {ttt[[1]], ttt[[2]]}
- but {ttt[[1]], ttt[[2]]} must not be further evaluated to {1,2}.

The idea is to manually control the evaluation process with `Hold`and `ReleaseHold`. I use too the fact that /. x->y is effective inside a Hold.

Otherwise, OwnValues[f] gives the internal rule attached to f (with Down Values,UpValues...). The rule attached to ttt are not used.

To see what's happening, one can use `ReleaseHold[Hold[f = {3, 4}] /. OwnValues[f]] // Trace // Column`. It is not too much verbose.

NB : The fact that `Set` has attribute `HoldFirst` seems a little bit contradictory with the fact that `{ttt[[1]],ttt[[2]]}={3,4}` works. I have used a partially "try and see what's happening" approach to find the solution.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I ask another question? Why this code doesn't work?  Table[With[{i = i}, HoldForm@ttt[[i]]], {i, 1, 2}] = {111, 222}

Comment: There are several reasons. The main one is that when you write `Table[...]]=...` , `Table[...` is not evaluated (because it's the fist argument of Set), that is to says it simply stays inert.  `Set[...]` treats most expressions like this. Lists (as in `{x,y}=...`) are exceptions (x and y are "extracted" from the expression {x,y}). I think a general rule of thumb is to autorise only lists and symbols to be on the left side of a `=`.

Comment: a little comment : Stack Exchange is not a chat. One Question at a time.

Comment: Thank you andre! So there is no way to set values to Table directly? I really need to do it this way, because I have defined a function which is a table, with different argument, the table will be different. And I want to set values to the table list in the program.