# direct assignment to the element in a Table

Tags: evaluation, list-manipulation, assignment, hold

I have already asked a related question here [why set values in this way doesn't work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24495/why-set-values-in-this-way-doesnt-work)
But I think I have to write the question which I encountered explicitly?

```
tmp = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
label[i_, p_] := i + p
test[p_] := Table[tmp[[label[i, p]]], {i, 1, 2}]
```

Here I defined a function `test` and the thing I want to is that change the values of list `tmp` via setting values to function `test`. While simply write

```
test[1]={111,222}
```

and expecting `tmp` will change to {1,111,222,3,4,5} is not possible.

So how to achive this? I have tried many `Hold` things, but failed.

Inspired by **andre**. I know that `Set` has attribute `HoldFirst`. So I tried `Evaluate`

```
 Evaluate[test[1]]={111,222}
```

this won't work! I guess the problem is that I must properly Hold `label[i,p]` and `tmp[[]]` in the table. But I can't work it out. Anyone help?

Comment: Errr ... why? `(tmp[[1 ;; Length@#]] = #) &@{11, 22, 33}`

Comment: `MapIndexed[(tmp[[#2]] = #1) &, {11, 22, 33}]`

Comment: @belisarius thank you belisarius. But I don't get it. What do you mean?

Comment: You're trying to build functionality upon side-effects. Although it's possible, better don't do that.

Comment: @belisarius thank you. So can you offer me a better way to achive my purpose? Or you said it's possible. I want to know how it is possible.

Comment: The two pieces of code above do what you want (I think)

Comment: The word "direct" in the title should be understood as "indirect" for most mathematica users. Here matheorem wants to modify a variable (tmp) without mentionning the name of the variable, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems rather convoluted, and there is almost certainly an easier way to approach whatever it is you are wishing to do, but I like answering questions like this as it allows working with more unusual aspects of the language.

We can do this:

```
Block[{tmp, Part}, Hold @@ {test[2]}] /. _[x_] :> (x = {111, 222});
```

As with my [previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24558/121) we may wish to wrap this into a more convenient syntax, but there is a problem; how do we know that `tmp` is the symbol to be blocked?  We can give it explicitly, if that is acceptable.

```
func_[boost2[expr_, sym__], arg___] ^:= 
  Block[{sym, Part}, Hold @@ {expr}] /. _[x_] :> func[x, arg]
```

Use syntax:

```
boost2[test[1], tmp] = {111, 222};
```

I'm not certain if there is any point in keeping the generalized form of this function in analogy to the original [`bump` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17553/121), but it was easy for me to write it this way.  If you wish only to have this operation apply to `Set` it may be simpler to write a `mySet` analog, like this:

```
SetAttributes[mySet, {HoldAll, SequenceHold}]

mySet[expr_, sym__, value_] := 
  Block[{sym}, Hold @@ {expr} // Quiet] /. _[x_] :> (x = value)

mySet[test[1], tmp, {111, 222}]
```

To me this syntax is not as elegant as the form above.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Wizard. Sorry for the late comment. I spent 10 hours reading mathematica docs and doing experiment on mathematica.In the end, I still can't make all that clear. I am really frustrated with my IQ. So here is the question, I think I don't have a good understanding of`Block`. For example, Why x=7;Block[{x},Print[x]] gives x not 7?? why `Block[{tmp},Hold@@{tmp[[1]]}]`gives `Hold[tmp[[1]]]`, while `Hold@@[tmp[[1]]]` gives 1 ?? And why your code include `Part` in the `Block` list. I tried remove the `Part`, though it will give error message, but the `tmp`really changes.

Comment: And I really don't understand   `func_[boost2[expr_, sym__], arg___] ^:=` . Why there is a Blank after `func`? what does it mean?

Comment: @matheorem You should read [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs); I particularly like [WReach's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/633/121) as it succinctly summarizes the behavior of these functions.  The reason I `Block` `tmp` and `Part` is to prevent either of them from evaluating *inside* the `Block[ . . . ]` allowing me to easily manipulate the expression without it evaluating all the way.

Comment: @matheorem the definition `func_[boost2[expr_, sym__], arg___] ^:=` is more complicated than it may need to be for your application.  It is an `UpSetDelayed` definition that will attach an UpValue to `boost2`.  The pattern `func_` will match any head (function) with arguments of the form `boost2[expr_, sym__], arg___`.  Please review [this documentation page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/FunctionsWithVariableNumbersOfArguments.html).

Comment: @matheorem I just noticed an error in my code above which I will correct now.  I will also add another example.

Comment: I corrected the error; in the new method I also removed `Part` from `Block` and added `Quiet` instead to suppress the error messages.  Either method may be used at your preference.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had been trying to think of other ways to do this, but all failed. And I have fully understood your thoughts of dealing this problem. Block together with Hold and then apply ruledelayed to achive the assignment, this approach is powerful and general!! You're awesome!!

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, Mr.Wizard. I have some more questions. First, I found that in the definition of function `boost2`. the `sym` in the `Block` will be red. It seems that _Mathematica_ think it is not right to write in this way. But why there is no any error message when using `boost2`. Second, I tried to define a seperate function that severs holding a table expression. I call it `holdtable`. `holdtable[tableexpr_, tobeheld__] := 
 Block[{tobeheld, Part}, Hold @@ {tableexpr}]`But when I use `holdtable` like `holdtable[test[1],tmp]`, the result is not right. `tmp` is not blocked.

Comment: @matheorem there are a number of places where "warning" syntax highlighting is applied to perfectly valid code; this is one of them.  Think of it as a "this may not work as you expect" warning.  Also, on your `holdtable` did you remember to set the `HoldAll` attribute as I did for my `mySet` function?

Comment: Thank you Mr.Wizard! I maybe a little anoying. But I have to make things clear, otherwise I will be very uncomfortable. Now I see I have to set `HoldAll` attribute to `tobeheld`, because otherwise it will be evaluated before being passed to `Block`. And I think that's why _MMA_ make `tobeheld` red, the red is quite reasonable to prevent error.

Comment: But why `boost2` doesn't have to be set to `HoldAll`?Of course, the code is more complicated than `holdtable`. It is a upsetdelayed and there is pattern match. But I didn't find the key to explain why the red in the definition of `boost2` is valid. I found that if I don't let `func` to be `Set` when using `boost2`, for example, I write `Join[boost2[test[1],tmp],{111,222}]` then the `tmp` passed to `Block` has been evaluated. This confused me a lot. I seems `boost2` is not perfect, right?

Comment: @matheorem You're not annoying, but this is probably better explained in Chat.  Unfortunately I don't have time tonight but I'll leave one more comment.  (1) The red highlighting is not because of any hold attribute or a lack thereof, but rather because the same symbol is used in a pattern in the left side of the `^:=` definition, which is a form of scoping construct, and also in the `Block` which is another scoping construct.  Compare with `Block[{x}, Block[{x}, 5]]`. (2) `HoldAll` was not needed for `boost2` because it is an UpValue and `Set` has `HoldFirst`; the rule acts before evaluation.