# Unexpected behavior of Unevaluated

Tags: programming, evaluation, hold

[This question of mine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25142/4330) got a bit ruined by the fact that I got a bit confused. I hope this separate question will take away this confusion. My confusion was that I found it strange that we have, for

```
x = 3;
g[_Symbol] := "yay"
```

that as expected

```
g[Unevaluated[x]]
```

> ```
> "yay"
> ```

but

```
g[_Symbol] := "yay"
g[Sequence[Unevaluated[x]]]
```

> ```
> g[Unevaluated[x]]
> ```

and even

```
With[
    {yyyy = g[Sequence[Unevaluated[x]]]}
  , Identity[yyyy]
]
```

> ```
> g[Unevaluated[x]]
> ```

The strange thing here is that even though `g[Unevaluated[x]]` is not in its "final form" (at a fixed point), in the sense that a rule can be applied to this as we can see above, Mathematica stops evaluating. I show the third example in which `With` occurs, because one might have thought that the behavior occurs because Mathematica assumes that rules for `g` have already been applied or something. But even when we use `With` (or in fact, `Identity`, `With` is really not necessary) to start a "clean evaluation", Mathematica refuses to do the last step.

For a little while, I had the following question/hypothesis about this: "Does Mathematica remember if an expression has been fully evaluated?". Using that I found another similar example. We have

```
Clear[h, somethingElse, something]
h[something, something = somethingElse]
```

> ```
> h[something, somethingElse]
> ```

even though, if we evaluate the resulting expression again, we have

```
h[something, somethingElse]
```

> ```
> h[somethingElse,somethingElse]
> ```

But this time, we have

```
Clear[h, somethingElse, something]
Identity[h[something, something = somethingElse]]
```

> ```
> h[somethingElse, somethingElse]
> ```

So that Mathematica does continue evaluation in this case. The same happens for a user-defined `Identity`. Note that the following does not result in a "fixed point" (expression that is left unchanged by the rules).

```
Clear[h, somethingElse, something]
List[h[something, something = somethingElse]]
```

> ```
> {h[something, somethingElse]}
> ```

Which probably makes sense. I guess Identity is defined in terms of a rule, and after a rule we have to evaluate again. However, if we put something in a list, we can assume that the thing inside the list was evaluated correctly so we don't have to evaluate again.

Little tentative conclusion: It is not true that Mathematica repeatedly evaluates an expression until it does not change anymore. It seems to be a little more subtle than that.

The question is: Is it a bug that

```
g[_Symbol] := "yay"
Identity[g[Sequence[Unevaluated[x]]]]
```

Evaluates to

> ```
>  g[Unevaluated[x]]
> ```

?

Comment: Towards an answer: David Withhoff, in Mathematica Internals (link below) on page 5, states that: "The internal structure of symbols and normal expressions also includes information that keeps track of the time of the last evaluation. An expression that has been evaluated once will not normally be evaluated again unless some part of the expression is modified. The system that implements this behavior is based on marking each expression with the time of the last evaluation. Strings and numbers do not require this information since they always evaluate to themselves."

Comment: link to David Withhoff's [Mathematica Internals](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flibrary.wolfram.com%2Finfocenter%2FDemos%2F4683%2FInternals.ps%3Ffile_id%3D4190&ei=IsKUUazbIYKW0AXp_oG4BA&usg=AFQjCNHwcgYCtTLmVQgFfJEL2NjZU0107w&bvm=bv.46471029,d.d2k&cad=rja)

Comment: Jacob, towards and answer to what?  I'm still not sure what you're asking.  I really wish I could be more help but with several of your questions now I can't quite grasp the idea.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard where to start... I seem to be speaking Chinese. But thanks for your efforts! If you are still online, maybe we can chat?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard note with both "-> expr" and "evaluates to expr" I mean that expr is the end result. `g[Unevaluated[x]]` is a strange end result as we can copy paste it into a new input cell and it will evaluate to "yay". Do you agree that that is unusual? (this is not what I feel is a bug... but its close :) )

Comment: @Mr.Wizard care to chat now? I've already made [the room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8839/discussion-between-mr-wizard-and-jacob)

Comment: Related: "[How does Mathematica determine that an evaluation should be terminated?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29343/280)"

Answer (score 14):

Jacob, allow me to suggest a presentation that I think you will find relevant and informative:

[Working with Unevaluated Expressions - Robby Villegas](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Courseware/377/)

Some excerpts:

> Unevaluated is a wrapper on arguments that is simply a signal to the
>   evaluator to avoid evaluating the argument. ... It is transparent to
>   the function receiving the argument.  You can think of it as a shuttle
>   giving the argument safe transport to the function's code, keeping the
>   evaluator away.  Unevaluated vanishes before the argument is fed to
>   the function, since its purpose is fulfilled.

Crucially:

> **Unevaluated must be wrapper before argument evaluation, not after, else it isn't stripped.**
>
> Recall our discussion of the over-arching evaluator, and the fact that
>   your inputs and commands have two stages:  their original form, and
>   the reduced form with arguments all evaluated.
>
> Unevaluated is not meant to be a function or stable data type.  It is
>   to be used as a wrapper on an argument in stage 1, before argument
>   evaluation.  It is a signal to the evaluator to suppress the usual
>   evaluation of that argument.
>   ...
>
> Those of you who have experimented with Unevaluated have found that in some situations it doesn't vanish.  This makes it seem confusing and inconsistent, like Sequence.
>   ...
>
> The subtle and confusing situation where Unevaluated persists is when an argument did not originally have a head of Unevaluated, but became Unevaluated[whatever] after argument evaluation finished.

Comment: +1, indeed relevant and informative! But really I know that Unevaluated persists "annoyingly" in this fashion, that is why I conjured the example with g[Sequence[Unevaluated[x]]] [in the first place](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25142/4330) ;). The remark that it is not supposed to be stabile data type hints that we may encounter bugs, though it may also just be a warning that we should be wary that Unevaluated can get stripped in its own unique way (like in a:=Unevaluated[b]). Again I think it is bad practise to let something evaluate to something to with head Unevaluated (...cont)

Comment: "inside a function" like g that has rules attached to it. So this supposed bug should never happen if we avoid this kind of situation. However, it still feels like a bug to me, or at least like a major exception to everything I know about the main loop and to me it suggests that there is something going on behind the scenes.

Comment: A rule of thumb I got from Wolfram support: "If `Unevaluated` appears around the argument of a function, it is removed.  If `Unevaluated` is inside the argument of a function, it is not removed." I interpret being inside the argument of a function as including being nested within an argument (e.g. `g[Sequence[Unevaluated[x]]]`) as well as as an own-value of the argument (e.g. g[var], where var is `Unevaluated[x]`).

Comment: @obsolesced By my reading that is covered in my answer above, or rather in the presentation from which I quote.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes I had asked support before chancing upon your answer, and wanted to provide additional confirmation, because this behavior of `Unevaluated` isn't described in its documentation.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not a bug. The hypothesis that Mathematica remembers if an expression has been evaluated turns out to be true. To see this, compare

```
Trace[{1, 2, oki}, TraceOriginal -> True]
```

> ```
> {{1,2,oki},{List},{1},{2},{oki},{1,2,oki}}
> ```

and

```
With[ 
    {expr = {1, 2, oki}}
  , (*ClearSystemCache[];*)
    Trace[expr, TraceOriginal -> True] 
]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, oki}
> ```

Note that this is not the result of caching in the sense of `ClearSystemCache`.

*Mathematica* seems to remember which symbols occur in expressions. It also remembers the last time an expression changed. Normally if a change is made to a symbol occurring in the expression, Mathematica will reevaluate this expression. This is why

```
Clear[h, somethingElse, something]

Identity[h[something, something = somethingElse]]
```

evaluates to `h[somethingElse, somethingElse]`. I do not know exactly what Mathematica stores and when. This is definitely something I'd like to learn more about.

One could now think that if we update `x`, using `Update` or assignment, we might cause such an update and the expression `g[Unevaluated[x]]` will still evaluate. It could be expected that

```
With[
    {expr = g[Sequence@Unevaluated@x]}
  , x = 4
  ; Identity[expr]
]
```

evaluates to `"yay"` (but it doesn't!). This is in fact also what I tried when I was answering this question, only I failed to mention it as I thought that was irrelevant.

However, the attribute `HoldAllComplete` of `Unevaluated` in the expression `g[Sequence @ Unevaluated @ x]` shields `x` from such the tracking of symbols. Mathematica does not store that `x` is present in `Unevaluated[x]`. It has no way to infer that `x` is present in `g[Unevaluated[x]]`. Therefore the expression above simply evaluates to `g[Unevaluated[x]]`. To see that it is really the attribute `HoldAllComplete` causing this, we can do

```
(*warning! Changes funtamental system definitions!*)

ClearAttributes[Unevaluated, HoldAllComplete]

SetAttributes[Unevaluated, HoldAll]

With[
    {expr = g[Sequence@Unevaluated@x]}
  , x = 4
  ; expr
]
```

> ```
> "yay"
> ```

Also consider, with a fresh kernel

```
gggg[y_Symbol, x_Symbol] := "yay";
Clear[x, y]

With[
    {expr = gggg[Sequence[y, Unevaluated[x]]]}
  , Update[y]
  ; expr
]

With[
    {expr = gggg[Sequence[y, Unevaluated[x]]]}
  , Update[x]
  ; expr
]
```

> ```
> "yay"
>
> gggg[y, Unevaluated[x]]
> ```

Where we see that `x` is not tracked but `y` is.

For more information (that I really should have included in this answer), see this [chat transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9510783?noredirect=1#9510783)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58340/discussion-on-answer-by-jacob-akkerboom-unexpected-behavior-of-unevaluated).

Answer (score 2):

Following the discussion in [Wagner's book](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16485/are-you-interested-in-purchasing-david-wagners-power-programming-with-mathemat/22724#22724) pages 192-3 with regards to Evaluation, I think one can figure out why this happens. The references to steps below refer to the steps in Wagner's book.

You start from `g[Sequence[Unevaluated[x]]` which is of the form `head0[part1]`. And where `part1` is of the form `head1[part2]`.

So in the first evaluation sequence: we start to evaluate `head0[part1]`. Now, `head0` is `g`, and it has no own-values, so we then move to evaluate `part1`  which is `Sequence[Unevaluated[x]]`. This starts another evaluation sequence.

For this second evaluation sequence, note that the head is `Sequence`. Then, the head `Unevaluated` is removed from `part2`. So by the end of step 7 of this second evaluation sequence, we have the expression `Sequence[x]`. There are no rules that apply here, so the evaluator restores the head `Unevaluated` (Step 16). So `part1` has now evaluated to `Sequence[Unevaluated[x]]`. Then, we go back to continue the first evaluation sequence.

Now we have finished step 7 of the first evaluation sequence and ended up with the following expression: `g[Sequence[Unevaluated[x]]`. Next, `Sequence` is spliced (Step 9), and we now have the expression `g[Unevaluated[x]]`. There are no other rules attached to this, and hence we are done.

EDIT: Actually, the link in Mr.Wizard's answer makes the point quite clear:

> The subtle and confusing situation where Unevaluated persists is when
>   an argument did not originally have a head of Unevaluated, but became
>   Unevaluated[whatever] after argument evaluation finished.

which is what happens in this case. Another way to see it:

```
ClearAll[h, g]
h = Function[z, Unevaluated[z], HoldAll];
g[_Symbol] := "yay";
x = 2;
g[h[x]]
```

returns

```
(* =>  g[Unevaluated[x]] *)
```

which is consistent with the description of the evaluation procedure above.

Comment: Hey ecoxlinux, thank you for your answer! I really like that you link to Wagners book. I hope to read that book very soon. I am sorry if my question was poor, but I feel you do not address all the things that may be confusing here. Two confusing aspects were to me: I thought it did not matter "how an expression came to be", it should should always evaluate the same. This turns out not to be true. Furthermore part of my confusion was that Unevaluated blocks updates. Sadly I failed to mention that I had tried this in my question, but I could not have known then. Please also see my answer.

Comment: You seemed to have raised several issues in the body of your question. I tried to answer the actual question you asked at the end of it (which is the same as  how you started). The update issues seemed to be a different point/question.

Comment: Yes. As I said, sorry if the question was poor. But the updates are fundamental in my opinion. If you don't know about them, you'd say Mathematica simply keeps reevaluating expressions. But then we cannot explain why g[Unevaluated[x]] can persist. It persists because Mathematica has no reason to reevaluate it.

Comment: OK, so if we were to do: ClearAttributes[Unevaluated, HoldAllComplete]; SetAttributes[Unevaluated, HoldAll]; g[_Symbol] := "yay"; x=4; g[Sequence[Unevaluated[x]]] then this still evaluates to g[Unevaluated[x]]. Then, it seems that it is not about updates.

Comment: Ah but the attribute HoldAllComplete blocks the updates :)

Comment: @Jacob, I removed the attribute to make that point.

Comment: I think the point is that in the example you constructed, when Sequence is removed, this happens after the Unevaluated head would have been taken into account. Hence (together with the fact that when Sequence[] is spliced, it does not triggers a re-evaluation of the entire expression), the inherited Unevaluated head remains.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, I misread. I agree with your last comment, except maybe about what the point is. I always thought it was a bad idea to have something evaluate an expression with head Unevaluated in this way, in the sense that Unevaluated will be there too late. The fact that g[Sequence[Unevaluated[x]]] evaluated to g[Unevaluated[x]] is just analogous to the other expression evaluating to h[something, somethingElse]. It is only upon returning again to the entire expression that Mathematica realises it has more evaluation to do. In both cases this is caused by the update, I think.