# Performance of Dispatch and lists of Rules

Tags: evaluation, replacement

*The issue outlined here seems to be no longer present in version 10, if you use a `Dispatch` table! This because a `Dispatch` table is now an atom.*

My question arose when I tried to answer [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25591/why-is-there-no-positionfunction-in-mathematica) by Mr.Wizard

Consider these definitions

```
Clear @@ Names["x" ~~ DigitCharacter ..]
rules2 = Array[Symbol["x" <> ToString[#]] -> # &, 100000 ];
dRules2 = Dispatch[rules2];
```

We have

```
AbsoluteTiming[Symbol["x" <> "100000"] /. dRules2]
```

> ```
> {0.000956,100000} (*version 9*)
> {0.000022,100000} (*version 10*)
> ```

```
AbsoluteTiming[Symbol["x" <> "100000"] /. rules2]
```

> ```
> {0.005132,100000} (*version 9*)
> {0.100221,100000} (*first time version 10*)
> {0.014408,100000} (*after first time version 10*)
> ```

It was to be expected that the dispatch tables are faster. It seems `Dispatch` tables became faster in V10, but regular replacement by a long list of rules become considerably slower. That is not the point here however, point is that the following breaks the dispatch table in version 9.

```
Update[x10]
AbsoluteTiming[Symbol["x" <> "100000"] /. dRules2]
```

> ```
>  {0.076655,100000} (*version 9*)
>  {0.000026,100000} (*version 10*)
> ```

```
Update[x10]
AbsoluteTiming[Symbol["x" <> "100000"] /. rules2]
```

> ```
>  {0.017523,100000} (*version 9*)
>  {0.063556,100000} (*version 10*)
> ```

Where all the evaluations have slowed down substantially (except there is no "first time delay" in version 10). The version 9 dispatch table is slower than the regular list of rules. I do not expect many people to use `Update`, but this should still be relevant to many people, as I believe an assignment causes an update. See an example further below.

I found out that updating a variable present in the list of rule causes the expression (list/dispatch table) containing the rules to be rebuilt. This takes a long time.

We can see that the rules get rebuilt from the following examples. Let

```
rules = {y1 -> 1, y2 -> 2, y3 -> 3};
```

Then

```
Trace[y1 /. rules, TraceOriginal -> True]
```

> ```
> {y1/. rules,{ReplaceAll},{y1},{rules,{y1->1,y2->2,y3->3}},y1/. {y1->1,y2->2,y3->3},1}
> ```

and

```
Update[y3]
Trace[y1 /. rules, TraceOriginal -> True]
```

> ```
>  {y1/. rules,{ReplaceAll},{y1},{rules,{y1->1,y2->2,y3->3},{List},{y1->1},{y2->2},
>  {y3->3,{Rule},{y3},{3},y3->3},{y1->1,y2->2,y3->3}},y1/. {y1->1,y2->2,y3->3},1}
> ```

In the second case we see the Trace is longer. We basically see that the expression `rules` gets rebuilt. The rule containing `y3` gets a little more attention.

An example where this does not happen is the following. Let

```
blockRules = {HoldComplete[x, 1], HoldComplete[y, 2], 
   HoldComplete[z, 3], HoldComplete[x, 4]};
```

Then we have

```
Equal @@ {Trace[Cases[blockRules, _[x, y_] -> y, 1, 1], 
    TraceOriginal -> True]
   Update[z]; 
  Trace[Cases[blockRules, _[x, y_] -> y, 1, 1], 
   TraceOriginal -> True]}
```

> ```
> True
> ```

despite the fact that we updated. HoldComplete prevents the tracking of symbols and therefore the expression does not get rebuilt.

The point is that I find this behaviuor of `Dispatch` (and also the lists of rules) very troubling. Note that HoldPattern will not save you, it does not have attribute HoldAllComplete, so even lists of rules with this wrapper will get rebuilt. Lists of rules will always contain many symbols, so the risk of updating one is very high I'd say.

To be complete, here is an example using HoldPattern. We have

```
hPRules = {HoldPattern[y1] -> 1, HoldPattern[y2] -> 2, 
   HoldPattern[y3] -> 3};
Unequal @@ {Trace[y1 /. hPRules, TraceOriginal -> True], Update[y3]; 
  Trace[y1 /. hPRules, TraceOriginal -> True]}
```

> ```
> True
> ```

The same happens for assignment. To be really complete, here is another example

```
Composition[Length, 
  Flatten] /@ {Trace[y1 /. hPRules, TraceOriginal -> True], y3 = 2; 
  Trace[y1 /. hPRules, TraceOriginal -> True]}
```

> ```
> {7, 18}
> ```

Where again our list of rules got rebuilt.

Well I guess the questions are a bit contrived. To share my worries was the main point. But here it is I guess:

In version 9, should we be very careful with `Dispatch` and lists of `Rule`s? Does anybody know a good way around this?

Comment: That's a good observation you made on `Update`, but `Update` is a rather special command. In my experience, I had at most a dozen cases where I really needed to use `Update` (i.e. it was crucial). I would think that the general message we should take home from your observation is that it is best to not use l-values (symbols or expressions which can be assigned values) as l.h.s. of rules (also in `Dispatch`), but I more or less follow this  practice in any case.

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin Thanks for the reply. I must admit I may have been a bit lazy, I believe the same thing happens when we use assignment instead of Update. But that screws up the list of rules anyway, unless we use HoldPattern. I will add/try an example with assignment and HoldPattern.

Comment: I think that in the context of usual (normal) lists of rules, performance is not the main concern, and `Dispatch` was introduced specifically to improve performance for long lists of rules. So I would not say that the behavior you have observed screws up lists of rules. Correctness comes first, and speed may be not even second. If you have huge lists of rules and want fast application, and also for robust resuts, I think it is in your best interest to make l.h.s. of rules immutable. Actually, in all practical cases I recall for `Dispatch`, this was the case.

Comment: Observe that if you call the dispatch table after the `Update` and before the substitution the substitution is not slowed down. So perhaps you need to "overload" `Update` in a such fashion that will also update the rules if a symbol contained in one is updated.

Comment: @Spawn1701D  I think that overloading `Update` is a horrible idea. It is obscure enough without being overloaded.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin he can try to implement something using `$Pre` or some other mechanism, the idea is to detect when an `Update` is called and update the dispatch tables if necessary.

Comment: @Spawn1701D the point is not really to use Update. I should have talked about assignment sooner. I believe assignment to a symbol causes an update to that symbol (through probably not through the function Update but rather some internal version I would say). I guess really only the examples with HoldPattern are relevant examples of cases where there is an unexpected slowdown that can occurr in practise. But still those seem significant

Comment: @Spawn1701D In the case of `Update`, I would not bother. It is *really* a rare and specialist command. Usually, it is used in rather exceptional circumstances and for non-trivial things. Besides, it is tightly connected to mutable changes and their propagation. So, I'd rather try to avoid situations where it may affect things, as I suggested in the previous comments.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom so in fact you want a mechanism to check the "sanity" of your dispatch tables.

Comment: @Spawn1701D Well really I wanted to share that I am at a loss about how to make dispatch tables containing common symbols that may be used for different things, without the dispatch table being reconstructed all the time. I can see no elegant solution to Mr.Wizards question for this reason. Oh btw also thanks for your comments :).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I think I will soon write a self answered question about the evaluator. I hope it does not become just a copy of [this Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25556/4330). I suppose I was too brief there. But I think the observations are crucial, for example for using dispatch tables :)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I suppose the "I" in I-values is for immutable then. Do you consider HoldPattern[x] to be immutable? I feel I should reply but I also feel I should look up immutable first :)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom The usual way `HoldPattern` is used is to prevent some patterns from evaluation. When wrapped around symbols, it is occasionally ok, but this is arguably not its main use. But if I understand correctly, your observation only affects the speed of rule application, not the result. When I have something like `HoldPattern[sym]`, I usually don't care about the speed so much. So, while I  agree that you made an interesting observation, I fail to see how this would affect e.g. code I personally write in the 99.9 percent of cases. So, for me, it is just a good warning. Of course, YMMV.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks, I will keep that in mind. I guess I am also focussed on the occurrence of HoldPattern in DownValues (which are not really used by the system, but still). Anyway, you understand correctly. Good night for now!

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Ok, that's an important note (`DownValues`).  You are right in that we may want to understand this issue a bit better. Good night!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out there are ways to protect your `Dispatch` tables in version 9 (again, all of this is not necessary in version 10)! That is, you do not have to make sure that all the symbols in your `Dispatch` table/list of rules get no assignments or updates made to them until you are done using your `Dispatch` table.

You simply have to shield them from evaluation and use `Unevaluated` just before you use them (with Replace etc). Lets have the following definitions

```
kkkk = 6;
Clear @@ Names["x" ~~ DigitCharacter ..]
rules2 = Array[Symbol["x" <> ToString[#]] -> # &, kkkk];
dRules = Dispatch[rules2];
```

We then have

```
Update[x3];
Cases[
  Trace[
   ReleaseHold@
    Hold[Replace][x1, 
     Apply[Unevaluated, Hold[dRules] /. OwnValues[dRules]]]
   ,
   TraceOriginal -> True
   ]
  ,
  Dispatch | Rule, Infinity] == {}
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Indicating no expression with head `Dispatch` or `Rule` was ever re-evaluated (check the full Trace if you want).

**Avoiding HoldPattern (unnecessary perfectionism?)**

Now I will also show how to avoid using `HoldPattern`. `HoldPattern` is a bit misleading, as it does not shield from updates. When we shield the `Dispatch` table from evaluation anyway, we carry the `HoldPattern`s around for no real reason. It can be convenient to use `HoldPattern` in the definition of a `Dispatch` table though. But I have found out this is not strictly necessary. Here is the way to avoid it. Let's have the following definitions as an example to work with.

```
x6 = 7; (*I show we can avoid this complication*)
stringSymbols = Array["x" <> ToString[#] &, 6];
symbolsCHeld = 
 Apply[HoldComplete, 
   List@ToExpression[stringSymbols, InputForm, Hold]][[All, All, 1]]

rulesCHeld =
 Apply[HoldComplete,
   List @@ 
    MapIndexed[
     Function[Null, With[{index = Last[#2]}, Hold[# -> index]], 
      HoldAll], symbolsCHeld, {2, 2}]][[All, All, 1]]
```

> ```
>  HoldComplete[{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6}]  
>  HoldComplete[{x1->1,x2->2,x3->3,x4->4,x5->5,x6->6}]
> ```

Now we can make our `Dispatch` table inside `Block` as follows. We do this inside `Block` as this allows the `Dispatch` table to be built correctly, even though `x6` has a value. Note that the code below assigns the returned value to `fragileCHeldDispatch`.

```
ReleaseHold@
 Hold[Block][symbolsCHeld, 
  Hold[Set][Hold[fragileCHeldDispatch], 
   rulesCHeld /. _[yyyy_] -> 
     Hold[HoldComplete @@ List@Dispatch[yyyy]]]]
```

> ```
> HoldComplete[Dispatch[{x1->1,x2->2,x3->3,x4->4,x5->5,x6->6},-DispatchTables-]]
> ```

Now, even if I had not set x6 in the beginning, the expression inside the HoldComplete would rebuild when exposed to evaluation. That is a downside of this approach (another being that we have to use Block in this crazy way). Anyway, we now have

```
Update[x3]
{
   Cases[
    #
    ,
    Dispatch | Rule, Infinity]
   ,
   Last[#]
   } &@

 Trace[
  ReleaseHold@
   Hold[ReplaceAll][Unevaluated[{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}], 
    Unevaluated @@ fragileCHeldDispatch]
  ,
  TraceOriginal -> True
  ]
```

> ```
> {{},{1,2,3,4,5,6}}
> ```

I hope I can soon use these techniques to provide an elegant answer to [Mr.Wizards question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25591/4330).