# Dispatch not behaving like a normal expression in Mathematica 10

Tags: version-10

In Mathematica 9, I used to be able to do

```
rules = Dispatch[{'a' -> 1, 'b' -> 2}]
rules[[1]]
```

to extract the rules from `Dispatch`wrapped list of rules. In Mathematica 10 the following error is raised:

```
Part::partd: Part specification Dispatch[...][[1]] is longer than depth of object. >>
```

Is this a bug? I am using only the trial version currently. I got aware of it because it breaks the [AutomaticUnits](http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/12/09/automatic-physical-units-in-mathematica/) package.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, this is not a bug.  `Dispatch` tables are now atomic:

```
Dispatch[{"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3}] // AtomQ
```

> ```
> True
> ```

As noted by user 18w [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54691/121) we can use [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Normal.html) to recover the rules.

```
Dispatch[{"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3}] // Normal
```

> ```
> {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3}
> ```

Comment: And (they became atoms) for good reason, Dispatch tables with symbols in them were hard to use properly. See [Performance of Dispatch and lists of Rules](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25619/4330). Maybe I should see if I can simplify my answer to your "[Why is there no PositionFunction in Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25591/4330)" Q&A. There was another issue with performance I think.

Comment: Sweet, `Dispatch` now works with `Verbatim`! The example in my answer (below "This may be because Dispatch just does not work well with Verbatim. Example:") now works!