# Choosing an initializer list in With

Tags: evaluation, assignment

I'm trying to have several initializer lists in a `With` function and choose which one I want to use. So far I have this:

```
With[Evaluate@{Unevaluated@{a = 2, b = 3}, Unevaluated@{a = 4, b = 6}}[[1]], a + b]
```

which doesn't work on a pretext that "*Local variable specification Unevaluated[{a=2,b=3}] is not a List.*", and gives me `With[Unevaluated[{a = 2, b = 3}], a + b]` for an answer. Now, if I just feed this same purportedly erroneous expression back to the kernel, it evaluates just fine with the correct result of 5, showing that Unevaluated list not being a list is a rather moot point. But how do I connect `Unevaluated` with `With` without me in between?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Your series of `Evaluate` and `Unevaluated` seem designed to confuse.

Comment: I want to calculate either `With[{a = 2, b = 3}, a+b]` or `With[{a = 4, b = 5}, a+b]`, selecting which one I want in a single place.

Comment: `case[1] := {a -> 2, b -> 3};
case[2] := {a -> 4, b -> 6};
a + b /. case[2]` What do you mean by a single place?

Comment: What is the criteria by which you sill select the first or the second `With`?

Comment: Maybe you can have `Module` instead of `With`? `selector[n_] := 
  Module[{}, case = {{a -> 2, b -> 3}, {a -> 4, b -> 6}}; 
   a + b /. case[[n]]]; selector /@ {1, 2}`

Comment: @rm-rf How do you propose to use Switch? Put it in every assignment? That's exactly the convoluted way I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @BlacKow, Neither `/.` nor `Module` are doing exactly what `With` does with regard to nested scopes with identically named variables (which I have plenty). Anyway I have three pages of code inside that `With` which is intended to work inside `With`, and this choosing is only used for testing and debugging, so I want it to stay inside `With`. The question is an academical one, there are lots of workarounds, of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [injector pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1929/injecting-a-sequence-of-expressions-into-a-held-expression/1937#1937) for that:

```
{Hold[{a = 2, b = 3}], Hold[{a = 4, b = 6}]}[[1]] /. Hold[init_] :> With[init, a + b]

(* 5  *)

{Hold[{a = 2, b = 3}], Hold[{a = 4, b = 6}]}[[2]] /. Hold[init_] :> With[init, a + b]

(* 10 *)
```

but you can see that `Hold` is preferred over `Unevaluated` in such cases.

As an alternative, you can define your own version of `With`, that would take the held version of initialization:

```
ClearAll[with]; 
SetAttributes[with, HoldRest];
with[Hold[init_], body_] := With[init, body];
```

and then

```
with[{Hold[{a = 2, b = 3}], Hold[{a = 4, b = 6}]}[[1]], a + b]

(* 5 *)

with[{Hold[{a = 2, b = 3}], Hold[{a = 4, b = 6}]}[[2]], a + b]

(* 10 *)
```

---

**EDIT**

As a bonus, here is a way to use your code verbatim - wrap it in `Block`:

```
Block[{With},        
    SetAttributes[With,HoldAll];        
    With[Evaluate[{Unevaluated[{a=2,b=3}],Unevaluated[{a=4,b=6}]}[[2]]],
        a+b
    ]
]

(* 10 *)
```

The explanation of why this works is left as an exercise to the reader :)

Comment: Thanks!, now by using `Thread[Hold[{{a = 2, b = 3}, {a = 4, b = 6}}]]`, I can have all initializers in a nice single matrix.

Comment: @panda-34 Yes, that's right. Thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 3):

Variations of this question have been asked before, e.g.:
[How to set Block local variables by code?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19758/121)
You may also find this question (and linked) of interest:  [Assigning values to a list of variable names](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6511/121)

Your question stands out because of your use of `Unevaluated` and the confusion that arises.  It is key to understand that `Unevaluated` must appear as the explicit head of an argument *before* evaluation for it to be stripped.  For this an other details of the use of `Unevaluated` please read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25308/121).

In this case you can use `Function` or (another) `With` to pass your extracted `Unevaluated` expression to `With`:

```
sets = {Unevaluated@{a = 2, b = 3}, Unevaluated@{a = 4, b = 6}};

With[#, a + b] &[First @ sets]

With[{x = First @ sets}, With[x, a + b]]
```

> ```
> 5
>
> 5
> ```

You could also leverage [this property](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2450/121) of `Part` to avoid having to apply `Unevaluated` (or `Hold`) to every set list manually.  Note that with `Unevaluated` you need the outer `{ }` to prevent this evaluating inside `Set`.

```
sets = {Unevaluated[{a = 2, b = 3}, {a = 4, b = 6}]};  (* ignore syntax warning *)

With[#, a + b] &[sets[[1, {1}]]]
With[#, a + b] &[sets[[1, {2}]]]
```

> ```
> 5
> 10
> ```

Or using the injector pattern than Leonid showed and `Hold`:

```
sets = Hold[{a = 2, b = 3}, {a = 4, b = 6}];

sets[[{1}]] /. _[x_] :> With[x, a + b]
sets[[{2}]] /. _[x_] :> With[x, a + b]
```