# Difference between the infinite rewriting behavior of evaluation and ReplaceRepeated

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching, argument-patterns

In the documentation [`tutorial/Evaluation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Evaluation.html#19212) it's said that:

> Every time the expression changes, the Wolfram Language effectively starts the evaluation sequence over again.

And in [`tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressions.html#22466):

> The general principle that the Wolfram Language follows in evaluating expressions is to go on applying transformation rules until the expressions no longer change.

A similar statement appears for [`ReplaceRepeated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html), too:

> `expr//.rules` repeatedly performs replacements until `expr` no longer changes.

But there're differences:

1. For `ReplaceRepeated`, it's replaced just once:

   ```
   ReplaceRepeated[h[], h@x___ -> (Print@1;h@x)]
   (* h[] *)
   ```
2. For rewriting involving a `Blank` pattern, infinite evaluation occurs:

   ```
   g[x_]:=g[x]
   Block[{$IterationLimit = 20},
       g[y]
   ]
   (* Message[$IterationLimit::itlim, 20] *)
   (* Hold[g[y]] *)
   ```
3. For transformation rules without generic patterns such as `Blank` and `Repeated`, it's rewrited only once.

   ```
   f[x]:=f[x]
   Trace@f[x]
   (* {f[x], f[x]} *)
   ```

What is the exact description of the condition for the termination of infinite rewriting?

Comment: I think this got downvoted because it's a bit confusingly worded and people didn't understand. But you're asking (and I'm not necessarily going to word it better, lol) what the difference is between how `ReplaceRepeated` decides evaluation is finished and how Mathematica's evaluation procedure decides that evaluation is finished (when rewriting expressions via `:=` definitions), right?

Comment: Also, I think it might be more clear to separate your examples so that it's clear what you're contrasting with what, e.g. `ReplaceRepeated`, then a blank line, then the `f` example, then a blank line, then the `g` example. I think this is an interesting question and I hope people understand it!

Comment: @thorimur Thank you for your advice and your understanding is right. I'd thought this statement is clear after evaluate the example given in the question. Maybe the non-canonical terminology "re-evaluation" is confusing. However, currently I'm not able to fetch reference.wolfram.com to cite the original description for improving this question further.

Comment: This question is interesting. Please reformulate to make some people happy.

Comment: "However, currently I'm not able to fetch reference.wolfram.com to cite the original description for improving this question further. " Can you quote the description in Chinese document? I can access the English document, but can't spot which part you're refering to.

Comment: @xzczd tutorial/Evaluation Section 1 "标准计算序列" Text 1: "下面是在计算例如 h[e1,e2,…] 的表达式的时候，Wolfram 语言所采取的步骤. 每当表达式发生改变时，Wolfram 语言重新开始计算的过程序列."

Comment: @xzczd tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressions Section 13 "控制无限运算" Text 1: "Wolfram 语言在运算表达式时，遵循的一般原则是不断应用转换规则，直到表达式不再更改为止. "

Comment: related: [How does Mathematica determine that an evaluation should be terminated?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29343/142), [Why x = x doesn't cause an infinite loop, but f([x_) := f(x) does?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39957/142).