# Manipulating slots in a pure function

Tags: functions

How does one manipulate the slot numbers in a pure function? Some trick with `Evaluate` or `Hold`? I'm aiming for something along the lines of:

```
(Slot /@ Range[19, 164, 29])& @@ {...}
```

**EDIT**

It turns out my actual problem is: why does

```
Evaluate[{Slot /@ Range[19, 164, 29]}] & @@ Range[164]
```

yield `{{19, 48, 77, 106, 135, 164}}` but

```
{Evaluate[Slot /@ Range[19, 164, 29]]} & @@ Range[164]
```

yields `{{#19, #48, #77, #106, #135, #164}}`?

Comment: [This answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6905/3066) to a previous question seems relevant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Responding to your updated question, which should probably be closed as a duplicate once someone takes the time to find the original: `Evaluate` only works when it is the explicit head of an argument.  In other words `Evaluate[ . . . ]` must appear as one of the arguments of the Head who's Hold attribute you wish to override.  You should read this paper, which teaches this among many other useful things:

- [Working with Unevaluated Expressions - Robby Villegas](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Courseware/377/)

As an example consider these lines:

```
Hold[1 + 1, Evaluate[2 + 2]]
Hold[1 + 1, {Evaluate[2 + 2]}]
Hold[1 + 1, Evaluate @@ {2 + 2}]
```

> ```
> Hold[1 + 1, 4]
>
> Hold[1 + 1, {Evaluate[2 + 2]}]
>
> Hold[1 + 1, Evaluate @@ {2 + 2}]
> ```

Note that only the first form evaluates.  On lines two and three the Heads of the second arguments are `List` and `Apply` rather than `Evaluate`.

A common method to get around this is to use [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/With.html) to inject an expression into the body of the function:

```
With[{body = Slot /@ Range[19, 164, 29]}, {body} &]

% @@ Range[164]
```

> ```
> {{#19, #48, #77, #106, #135, #164}} &
>
> {{19, 48, 77, 106, 135, 164}}
> ```

If you want to evaluate the *entire* body every time you can just `Apply` `Function` to a `List` of the components that form the `Function`:

```
(Function @@ {{Slot /@ Range[19, 164, 29]}}) @@ Range[164]
```

> ```
> {{19, 48, 77, 106, 135, 164}}
> ```

Comment: +1 for detailed explanation, concur that part is duped *somewhere*...

Comment: @rasher Thanks.  Let me know if you find that duplicate.

Comment: @MrWizard Thanks, this is very helpful. Also scanned for the dup but didn't see it

Comment: Thanks for the link. The Villegas paper is a "must read".

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6905/3066) is the previous answer you are trying to remember?

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks. That could be the one.  I don't think these are quite similar enough to close; do you agree?

Comment: I wouldn't close. The cited answer is related and should be linked to this one, which I have done (both here and ina comment to the question)

Comment: Related: [(25266)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25266/121)

Answer (score 3):

E.g.,

```
Evaluate[Slot /@ Range[1, 5, 2]] & @@ {1, 2, a, 4, 5, 6, 7}

(*  {1,a,5}  *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It made me realize I wasn't asking the right question; I've edited the post.

Comment: @mfvonh: Look at the `FullForm` of each. One produces a function with a list of slots, the other produces a function with a list with only one entry: `Evaluate[Map[Slot, Range[19, 164, 29]]]` giving you the list of *unevaluated* slots...