# Explicit use of Evaluate not behaving the way I expect it to

Tags: function-construction, evaluation

I discovered a strange behavior of the `Evaluate` function.

Case 1:

```
Clear[f]
f[x_] := x^2
g[x_] := Evaluate[D[f[x], x]]
Clear[f]
g[x]
```

> ```
> 2 x
> ```

Case 2:

```
Clear[f]
f[x_] := x^2
g[x_] := Evaluate[D[f[x], x]] + f[x]
Clear[f]
g[x]
```

> ```
> f[x] + Derivative[1][f][x]
> ```

I think the Case 2 behavior is strange, because the derivative of `f` isn't evaluated properly when `g` defined.

Why do I see this difference?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, thanks for taking the effort to state well formated question :)

Comment: Thank you for your quick and easy-to-understand reply!

Comment: I feel compelled to ask for the reopening of this question. I do not think it duplicates the question Mr.Wizard identifies as being duplicated. This question is about the explicit use of `Evaluate` at different levels of an expression and it's interaction with `SetDelayed`. The other question is about the explicit use of `Evaluate` and it's interaction with `Function`. For experienced _Mathematica_ users, the two question are related, so it is no coincidence that part of Mr.Wizard's answer to the other question is applicable to this question. ...

Comment: ... But, despite the relationship, I assert that this question is sufficiently different that less experienced users, should they follow the link, will be more confused than enlightened. Should this question be reopened, I suggest the link to the other question be given in a comment.

Comment: @m_goldberg Okay, we'll try it your way.  I posted a *modified* version of my original answer here.  I await the community's feedback.

Comment: Thanks for a lot of response. Actually, I knew a solution just using `Set`. But, although I have used _Mathematica_ for 4 years, I didn't know the real behavior of `Evaluation` and I felt that is strange! For me, the references Mr.Wizard denoted are useful and I got more deeply understanding about _Mathematica_. Anyway, thank you again for your good answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is because `Evaluate` works only on the first level of held expression. Take a look:

You are using `SetDelayed` while creating `g`, it has `Attribute` `HoldAll`:

```
Attributes@SetDelayed
```

> ```
> {HoldAll, Protected, SequenceHold}
> ```

so effectively, the right hand side of your definition is:

```
Hold[Evaluate[D[f[x], x]]] // FullForm (*first case*)
```

> ```
> Hold[Derivative[1][f][x]]
> ```

```
Hold[Evaluate[D[f[x], x]] + 1] // FullForm (*second case*)
```

> ```
> Hold[Plus[Evaluate[D[f[x],x]],1]]
> ```

As you can see, in the latter case `Evaluate` is deeper and is not going to work.

It is quite important issue and, imo, not stressed enough in documentation. You can read about it in `PossibleIssues` section of [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Evaluate.html).

Comment: It's also mentioned in the Details section.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Agree, but that sentence is quite convolved for new users :) or at least it was for me ;)

Answer (score 2):

Kuba explained what went wrong. This example will show you how to get the behavior you were probably expecting. Just use `Set` ( = ) instead of `SetDelayed` ( := ). This will get `f` evaluated at right time and will work for arbitrarily deeply nested calls to `f`.

```
Clear[f, g, h, x]
f[x_] := x^2
g[x_] = D[f[x], x] + f[x];
h[x_] = (1 + f[x]^3)/D[Log[f[x]], x];
Clear[f]
{g[x], h[x]}
```

> {2 x + x^2, 1/2 x (1 + x^6)}

Answer (score 2):

`Evaluate` only works when it is the explicit head of an argument.  In other words `Evaluate[ . . . ]` must appear as one of the arguments of the Head who's Hold attribute you wish to override.  You should read this paper, which teaches this among many other useful things:

- [Working with Unevaluated Expressions - Robby Villegas](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Courseware/377/)

As an example consider these lines:

```
Hold[1 + 1, Evaluate[2 + 2]]
Hold[1 + 1, {Evaluate[2 + 2]}]
Hold[1 + 1, Evaluate @@ {2 + 2}]
```

> ```
> Hold[1 + 1, 4]
>
> Hold[1 + 1, {Evaluate[2 + 2]}]
>
> Hold[1 + 1, Evaluate @@ {2 + 2}]
> ```

Note that only the first form evaluates.  On lines two and three the Heads of the second arguments are `List` and `Apply` rather than `Evaluate`.

In your example the outer function with a hold Attribute is `SetDelayed` rather than `Hold`, but the same logic applies.

A common method to get around this is to use [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/With.html) to inject an expression into the body of the definition:

```
Clear[f]
f[x_] := x^2

With[{body = D[f[x], x]},
  g[x_] := body + f[x]
]

Clear[f]
g[x]
```

> ```
> 2 x + f[x]
> ```

If you want to evaluate the *entire* right-hand-side, as in your first example, merely use `Set` instead of `SetDelayed`, and eliminate `Evaluate`:

```
Clear[f, g]
f[x_] := x^2

g[x_] = D[f[x], x];

Clear[f]
g[x]
```

> ```
> 2 x
> ```

(If this answer seems strangely familiar that's because [it is](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46753/121); call this an experiment in following the advice to reopen.)