# How to correct this, `f[a_] := FindRoot[eq == 0, {x, 0.5}]`, where `eq` contains a parameter $a$, without using `eq[a]`?

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, evaluation

I want to solve an equation with a parameter $a$, and define the result as a function of $a$. It is something like this:

```
f[a_] := FindRoot[x^2 + 2 x + a == 0, {x, 0.5}]
f[0.2]
(* -> {x -> -0.105573} *)
```

The equation I want to solve is a large expression, so I do not want to put it explicitly inside the `FindRoot`. But this does not work:

```
eq := x^2 + 2 x + a;
f[a_] := FindRoot[eq == 0, {x, 0.5}]
f[0.2]
(* -> FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {1.25 +a} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {x} = {0.5}. *)
```

I do not want to define the equation as `eq[a]`, because this equation is also used to do other things, for which it is better to just use `eq`. The following ways also do not work:

```
f[a_] := FindRoot[Evaluate[eq] == 0, {x, 0.5}]
f[a_] := Evaluate[FindRoot[eq == 0, {x, 0.5}]]
```

(However, if we want to solve the above equation analytically, `f[a_] := Evaluate[Solve[eq == 0, x]]` works, and `f[a_] := Solve[Evaluate[eq] == 0, x]` does not. How to explain this?)

Comment: I think it is a duplicate of: [Explicit use of Evaluate not behaving the way I expect it to](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47907/5478). Well it is if your question is only " How to explain this?".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you can use the following

```
eq := x^2 + 2 x + a;
Function[f[a_] := FindRoot[# == 0, {x, 0.5}]][eq]
```

to define your `f`.

Comment: Wow!... Interesting crazy code injection. This is the kind of operations that make new users get in a non excited state about Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to halirutan's answer, you could define `f` like this

```
eq := x^2 + 2 x + a;
Unevaluated[
  f[a_] := FindRoot[eq == 0, {x, 0.5}]
  ] /. OwnValues[eq]
```

Using `Unevaluated` in the first argument of `ReplaceAll` like this is similar to, but avoids, `With`. You cannot use `With` here, because `With` will try to prevent that the `a` in `a_` and the `a` in `eq` match.

Note that here `eq` is never really evaluated, so that we even get a solution if `x` has a value.

Also `ReleaseHold` is totally pro (`x` cannot have a value now)

```
eq := x^2 + 2 x + a;
Clear@f
ReleaseHold@
 Hold[SetDelayed][f[a_], Hold[FindRoot][eq == 0, {x, 0.5}]]
f[0.2]
```

> {x -> -0.105573}

Comment: Very nice, thanks ;) I was thinking about this but I forgot about `OwnValues`. I think it's the first time I see it can be really useful :) #newbie

Comment: @Kuba Well, I saw you use `ReleaseHold` today too, which is totally pro :P. Actually I could probably use that here :P

Comment: My version with `ReleaseHold` was not working, I was not aware about sneaky little `With` renaming variables. I'm glad you can't see deleted answers :P my is full of pro solutions like: `With[{e = eq},
 ToExpression[ MakeBoxes[f[a_] := FindRoot[e == 0, {x, 0.5}]] /. "a$_" -> "a_"]
 ]`

Comment: @Kuba as long as you are the first to answer, it is ok to show off your knowledge of functions that are not really necessary, don't you think :P? I agree `With` is quite sneaky. The behaviour is mentioned in the docs under With>possible issues, though.

Comment: oh thank you, now I'm feeling better :P