# Using "With" outside a function on its parameters

Tags: function-construction

I am making complex 3d graphics, and to clear up functions, I want to use `With` to remove a repeated action. This action occurs many times through many functions, so I want the `With` outside all of them, so I only declare it once. Except Mathematica doesn't seem to like having a `With` outside a function, if it is replacing parameters. A simplified version is shown below:

```
With[{y = x},
 draw[x_] := Cylinder[{{y,0,0}, {y+1,0,1}}, 0.1]
 ...(*other functions:See Bottom!!!!!!!!*)
]
```

then:

```
Graphics3D[draw[3]]
```

If I do the above, it brings the error:

[image: The Error]

So it should go y -> x -> 3. But it only gets half-way. It has changed y to x but I think it is after when the parameters are put in, so x is not changed to 3. Is there a way to keep the `with` outside, so it is only declared once.

Also, in case anybody says put the `With` before `cylinder`. No, I don't want to do that, as there are other functions using the values changed by "With"

-----------------------EDIT-----------------------------

The answers can replace the values for one function, as is shown in the code example, but it doesn't show (although I did say it), that it needs to work through many functions, as shown below. Sorry for the confusion, as causing the first two answers to not fully work.

```
With[{y = x},
 draw1[x_] := Cylinder[{{y, 0, 0}, {y + 1, 0, 1}}, 0.1], 
 draw2[x_] := Cylinder[{{y, 0, 0}, {y + 1, 0, 1}}, 0.2]
 ...(*more functions*)
]
```

Comment: The way you have draw set up, x is defined within draw as a parameter.  Outside of draw, x is just a symbol x, so for example `draw[3]` will yield the output `Cylinder[{{x, 0, 0}, {x, 0, 0}}, 0.1]`.  In other words, Mathematica doesn't think the formula you've given it for `draw` involves the input variable at all.

Comment: closely related, maybe duplicate: [48521](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48521/5478). So you can proceed with `Function[
  draw[x_] := Cylinder[{{#, 0, 0}, {# + 1, 0, 0}}, 0.1]
  ][x]`, notice I've added `+1` since your code makes no sense.

Comment: [related tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VariablesInPureFunctionsAndRules.html)

Comment: @Kuba,@Jacob Akkerboom. Yes you are both right, my code it incorrect, in both the ways you two stated, I have now changed it.

Comment: Responding to your edit: `Function[
  draw1[x_] := Cylinder[{{#, 0, 0}, {# + 1, 0, 1}}, 0.1];
  draw2[x_] := Cylinder[{{#, 0, 0}, {# + 1, 0, 1}}, 0.2];][x]`

Comment: Also closely related, arguably duplicate: [(20766)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mismatch in your definition, between `x` and `x$`

```
draw // Information
```

> Global`draw
>
> ```
> draw[x$_]:=Cylinder[{{x,0,0},{x,0,0}},0.1]...
> ```

This is because `With` is a so called scoping construct. `With` tries to avoid conflicts between symbols. See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46613/4330) for a good explanation by Leonid. If you want to know all cases in which this happens, see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48639/4330) by me.

If you wish to avoid such behaviour, you can use `ReplaceAll` on the outside, rather than `With`. There is another issue with your code too, as the two points in the first argument of `Cilinder` have to be different. So I have changed this. You could then use the following code

```
Unevaluated[draw2[x_] := Cylinder[{{y,0,0}, {y,0,1}}, 0.1]]/. Unevaluated[y->x]
```

Because the syntax with `Unevaluated` is a bit ugly, you may consider making your own function, like this.

```
SetAttributes[replaceWith, HoldFirst]
(*Unevaluated[y] is to make sure replaceWith works well when providing 
Unevaluated around its second argument*)
replaceWith[x_,y_]:= Unevaluated[x]/.Unevaluated[y]
```

The solution is then

```
replaceWith[
 draw2[x_] := Cylinder[{{y, 0, 0}, {y, 0, 1}}, 0.1]
 ,
 Unevaluated[y -> x]
 ]
```

In both cases, we have

```
draw2 // Information
```

> Global`draw2
>
> ```
>  draw2[x_]:=Cylinder[{{x,0,0},{x,0,1}},0.1]
> ```

**Edit**

You asked to make it work for multiple definitions. The solution is simply as follows

```
replaceWith[
 draw1[x_] := Cylinder[{{y, 0, 0}, {y + 1, 0, 1}}, 0.1];
 draw2[x_] := Cylinder[{{y, 0, 0}, {y + 1, 0, 1}}, 0.2]
 ,
 y -> x
 ]
```

Note that I have replaced a colon of yours by a semicolon. I prefer it this way, as this corresponds more closely to `With` (note that syntax in  the example you provided was not correct). We then have

```
Graphics3D[{draw1[1], draw2[1]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

When you do this, localization kicks in and renames one of the `x` to avoid conflict:

[image]

This is in general beneficial, and designed to prevent trouble.  In some situations, however, you don't want this localization-through-renaming to happen.  In that case you can use `Replace` instead of `With` to replace `y` by `x`.

I like to keep using the syntax of `With` though, so in these situations I tend to use the `withRules` function defined in the middle of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/993/12).

[image]

The caveat with `withRules` is precisely that it does not truly localize, so you need to be very careful when using it.

---

**Update:**

Version 10-specific template based solution:

```
template = (draw[x_] := Cylinder[{{#y, 0, 0}, {#y + 1, 0, 1}}, 0.1]) &

template[<| "y" :> x |>]

?draw
```

> ```
> draw[x_]:=Cylinder[{{x,0,0},{x+1,0,1}},0.1]
> ```

Comment: I see our answers are quite similar :). I must say I don't like a definition using ``Internal`InheritedBlock`` on `Rule` and `RuleDelayed` though. That is not necessary in my opinion. Moreover, the Front End also us `Rule` and `RuleDelayed` and modifying their behaviour may interfere with dynamic behaviour. But I suppose my own function isn't perfect either  :).

Comment: @Jacob The modification is temporary (localized), so it shouldn't cause any problems.  I guess you are referring to the situation when the main evaluation is interrupted by a pre-emptive one (dynamic) and the modification is still in effect.  Yes, that can be a problem with any similar use of `Block` as well ... I think that's a general problem with the language.  The way you defined `replaceWith`, it's not going to allow evaluation on the RHS of `->` (not `:>`) while also being self-contained.

Comment: @Jacon [I think this warrants a separate discussion.  If you can add something interesting, please post a response.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54683/12)

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this :

```
With[{y = x},
  SetDelayed @@ {Unevaluated[draw[x_]], 
    Unevaluated[Cylinder[{{y, 0, 0}, {y + 1, 0, 1}}, 0.1]]}
];
```