# Is the use of Block to temporarily override definitions inherently unsafe?

Tags: dynamic, scoping, core-language

This may have been discussed before, if so, please let me know.

---

Consider the following example:

```
x = 5

Dynamic[{Clock[], x}]
```

This will always display the current value of `x`.

Now evaluate

```
Block[{x}, Pause[5]]
```

Notice that `x` loses its global value!

---

**Question:**

`Block` is commonly used to temporarily override definitions of user-defined symbols, package symbols, or built-ins.  (There's also `` Interal`InheritedBlock ``.)

What if, while the main (synchronous) evaluation is in the middle of a `Block`, it is interrupted by a [pre-emptive (asynchronous)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html#681967067) evaluation?  This pre-emptive evaluation could come from some `Dynamic` construct in the front end or from a [scheduled task](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/TimedEvaluations.html).

The `Block` in the main evaluation could potentially wreak havoc in the (supposedly independent) pre-emptive evaluation.  This could cause very difficult to debug timing-dependent bugs that seem to occur completely randomly.  This is very likely to happen if `Block` is used to override a builtin.

Comment: I find it quite disappointing that for every advanced programming trick in Mathematica there seems to be a situation where it can cause serious problems.  I usually stay away from these types of tricks, but now it looks like even those that I thought to be safe before have their own problems.

Comment: [This question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25673/how-safe-is-the-use-of-block-and-internalinheritedblock/) might be relevant.

Comment: @Leonid Thanks, it's a duplicate!

Comment: Ok, if you say so. Will vote to close then.

Comment: Right, that does happen in version 8, too. It's indeed a duplicate. So this doesn't explain my current v. 10 issues with inputs suddenly becoming "unevaluated" - I haven't even been able to isolate it enough to ask a question about it... very frustrating, it's some `Dynamic` thing.

Answer (score 1):

One potential solution to this would be using `PreemptProtect` to prevent interruption.

For the example from the main question,

```
PreemptProtect@Block[{x}, Pause[5]]
```

Comment: Just thinking aloud ...