# Cases with Alternatives failed

Tags: pattern-matching

Consider this list of rules

```
rules = {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}
```

I'd like to fish some of the rules out of such a list using `Cases`. All is well if I hard code the `Alternatives` to fish out:

```
Cases[rules, HoldPattern[a|b -> _]]
```

> {a -> 1, b -> 2}

But, if I try to dynamically generate the `Alternatives` from data, it fails:

```
targets = {a, b}
Cases[rules, HoldPattern[Alternatives @@ targets -> _]]
```

> {}

I've tried the following shots-in-the-dark

```
Cases[rules, HoldPattern[Evaluate[Alternatives @@ targets] -> _]]
```

> {}

```
Cases[rules, HoldPattern[ReleaseHold[Alternatives @@ targets] -> _]]
```

> {}

MMA 10.0.2.0 on Mac Mavericks.

Comment: Related: [(3916)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3916/121), [(6894)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6894/121),
[(47907)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47907/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HoldPattern` has attribute `HoldAll`

```
Attributes[HoldPattern]
(* {HoldAll, Protected} *)
```

So one can use the following injection

```
Cases[rules, HoldPattern[Alternatives@## -> _] & @@ targets]
(* {a -> 1, b -> 2} *)
```

P.S. Conceptually, `HoldPattern` is here the wrong tool for the job, even if this works. See Leonid's answer.

Comment: Nice reminder of the general utility of thunking (wrapping an expression in a function).

Comment: Note that my original expression is equivalent to `Cases[rules, HoldPattern[Alternatives@@## -> _]& @ targets`, so the deeper lesson is about the distinction between `Apply`, `@@`, and ordinary application `@`.

Answer (score 6):

#### The issues with your code

There are two different issues here. First is that indeed, `HoldPattern` would prevent `Alternatives@@...` to evaluate. This is why

```
Cases[rules, HoldPattern[Alternatives @@ targets -> _]]
```

will *not* work. However, when you use

```
Cases[rules, HoldPattern[Evaluate[Alternatives @@ targets]] -> _]
```

you run into another issue: `Cases` has an extended syntax `Cases[expr, lhs_->rhs_,...]`, where it interprets `Rule` as a part of its extended syntax, rather than a part of expression to be matched. Conceptually, the correct solution here would be, for example, to use `Verbatim` to escape `Rule`:

```
Cases[rules,Verbatim[Rule][HoldPattern[Evaluate[Alternatives @@ targets]], _]]

(* {a -> 1, b -> 2} *)
```

#### HoldPattern and Verbatim

However, I have to note that the whole business with `HoldPattern` here seems either unnecessary or insufficient. If you don't worry about possible evaluation of `a`, `b`, etc, then you don't need `HoldPattern`:

```
Cases[rules, Verbatim[Rule][Alternatives @@ targets, _]]

(* {a -> 1, b -> 2} *)
```

So, it looks like a classic case of misuse of `HoldPattern`, where you use `HoldPattern` where `Verbatim` should be used.

OTOH, if you do worry about evaluations of `a`, `b`, etc, then you need to do a whole lot more to prevent their evaluation, than just in the line with `Cases`. But this doesn't seem to be the case you are interested in.

Comment: The documentation (under "Cases" -> "Possible Issues") sets the trap by recommending `HoldPattern` when matching rules in `Cases`.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin Then the documentation isn't quite right :) This is not the only place where docs miss the point. I will eventually make a suggestion report to change this.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin Historically, there were times when both `HoldPattern` and `Verbatim` were the same, named `Literal` (which had, essentially, the functionality of `HoldPattern` rather than `Verbatim`). It was precisely the realization that the role of pattern escaping is different from the role of pattern-transparent holding wrapper (preventing pattern evaluation), that led to the introduction of `HoldPattern` and `Verbatim`, instead of `Literal`.

Comment: I also notice that you wrote `HoldPattern[Evaluate[Alternatives @@ targets]] -> _`, where my (guessworky) attempt was `HoldPattern[Evaluate[Alternatives @@ targets] -> _]` because I did appreciate the extended syntax of `Cases` and tried to wrap my `HoldPattern` around the whole thing.  Still doesn't work...  I have some more learning to do about `Verbatim` versus `HoldPattern`.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin Well, your code was missing ending brackets, so there were a number of ways to interpret what you had in mind.

Comment: You're right -- that's what I get for typing code by eye from my Notebook rather than cutting and pasting (I just hate reaching for a mouse -- it's like a cache miss in the brain).  I promise it was in a Notebook the way I meant :)  will update the sample.

Comment: It's interesting that the top-level docs for `Verbatim` only show examples where the argument of `Verbatim` is a pattern with blanks. Without deeper study, it's difficult to discover from the docs that `Verbatim[Rule][...]` would do anything worthwhile, because there aren't any obvious "substitutions for blanks or other transformations" (quoting the docs) that `Verbatim` escapes in this case.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin Yes, I agree - the docs don't do a good job for `Verbatim`. You can read the relevant chapter in David Wagner's book though, he has a very illuminating discussion of these issues.

Comment: Roger that.  Here's a link to the book, heroically recovered by the MMA.SE mavens, just in case someone needs it from here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16485/are-you-interested-in-purchasing-david-wagners-power-programming-with-mathemat

Answer (score 2):

This should probably be a comment (and maybe I have missed it):

This does not address the issue re: `Alternatives` but note `FilterRules` does this.

```
rules = {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3};
FilterRules[rules, {a, b}]
```

or

```
rules = {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4}
FilterRules[rules, {d, a, b}]
```

yields: {a -> 1, b -> 2, d -> 4}

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to keep `Cases` from seeing the second argument as a rule.  Adding a [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html):

```
Cases[rules, x : (Alternatives @@ targets -> _)]
```

> ```
> {a -> 1, b -> 2}
> ```

Not nearly as clean as [`FilterRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FilterRules.html) but a bit more general.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use [`PatternSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternSequence%60.html) which does evaluate its argument:

```
Cases[rules, PatternSequence[Alternatives @@ targets -> _]]
```

> {a -> 1, b -> 2}

Answer (score 1):

This question already has several answers, but I'd like to comment on why the OPs initial attempt to use `Evaluate` failed (even though they were so close to victory). The following attempt was made for the matching pattern:

```
HoldPattern[Evaluate[Alternatives @@ targets] -> _]
```

The problem here is that `Evaluate` simply will not do anything. Look at the `FullForm` of this expression:

```
HoldPattern[Rule[Evaluate[Apply[Alternatives, targets]], Blank[]]]
```

As you can see, `Evaluate` is still there, meaning that it didn't... Well, evaluate. This is a common misunderstanding about how `Evaluate` works: it will only override a `HoldAll` attribute if it appears as a head directly one level down inside of a function that has a hold attribute. In this case, `Evaluate` appears inside of `Rule`, where it will do nothing (and can't, since rule doesn't have any hold attributes).

To clarify the point, try evaluating the following two expressions:

```
Hold[Evaluate[1 + 1]]
(*Hold[2]*)
Hold[{Evaluate[1 + 1]}]
(*Hold[{Evaluate[1 + 1]}]*)
```

In short, `Evaluate` cannot work at a deeper level of a held function.

Going back to the original question, we can now understand why the original attempt didn't work, but this one does:

```
targets = {a, b};
Cases[
  {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}, 
  HoldPattern[Evaluate[Alternatives @@ targets -> _]]
]

Out[15]= {a -> 1, b -> 2}
```