# Different behaviours of Cases

Tags: functions, pattern-matching

Why does `Cases[]` output an element only in the first of the following lines?

```
Cases[{1, a -> 2 b}, HoldPattern[a -> 2 b]]
(*{a->2b}*)
Cases[{1, a -> 1/2 b}, HoldPattern[a -> 1/2 b]] 
(*{}*)
Cases[{1, a -> π b}, HoldPattern[a -> π b]] 
(*{}*)
Cases[{1, a -> c b}, HoldPattern[a -> c b]] 
(*{}*)
```

Comment: compare `FullForm@HoldPattern[a -> 1/2 b]` and `FullForm@{1, a -> 1/2 b}`, the rest is about reordering.

Comment: Huh, that was a nasty one!

Comment: Use `PatternSequence` in place of `HoldPattern`

Comment: @kglr I think that is worth an answer and an explanation. (I'm personally interested.)

Comment: See also this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73020/5478

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, the explanation is in Kuba's comment and Giancarlo's answer; that is, `HoldPattern`  is `HoldAll`, hence does not evaluate its argument, whereas `PatternSequence` does evaluate its argument.

Comment: @kglr: Wow, an interesting hack! Just like `HoldPattern`, the head `PatternSequence` shields `Rule` from being interpreted by `Cases`, but does not have the `HoldAll` attribute, allowing the pattern to evaluate first! Wondering if there are subtleties tho.

Comment: @kglr have not thought about this, nice, better: `Cases[{1/b -> 2}, 1/b -> 2 // PatternSequence]` than `Cases[{1/b -> 2}, Verbatim[Rule][1/b , 2]]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an alternative to `HoldPattern[Evaluate[...]` you can use [`PatternSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternSequence.html) which evaluates its argument:

```
{Cases[{1, a -> 2 b}, PatternSequence[a -> 2 b]],
 Cases[{1, a -> 1/2 b}, PatternSequence[a -> 1/2 b]],
 Cases[{1, a -> π b}, PatternSequence[a -> π b]],
 Cases[{1, a -> c b}, PatternSequence[a -> c b]]}
```

> {{a -> 2 b}, {a -> b/2}, {a -> b π}, {a -> b c}}

Alternatively, give the pattern a name:

```
{Cases[{1, a -> 2 b}, p : (a -> 2 b)],
 Cases[{1, a -> 1/2 b}, p : (a -> 1/2 b)],
 Cases[{1, a -> π b}, p : (a -> π b)],
 Cases[{1, a -> c b}, p : (a -> c b)]}
```

> {{a -> 2 b}, {a -> b/2}, {a -> b π}, {a -> b c}}

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Kuba's comment now I see:
`HoldPattern` prevents the evaluation of its argument, so `Cases` don't match the element in the list `a->b/2` that is

```
Times[Rational[1, 2], b]
```

with the unevaluated pattern

```
Times[b, Power[2, -1]]
```

Evaluate the argument of `HoldPattern` solves the problem:

```
Cases[{1, a -> b/2}, HoldPattern[Evaluate[a -> b/2]]]
(*{a -> b/2}*)
```

Thanks Kuba!

Comment: You can define `myHoldPattern[x___] = HoldPattern[x];` and use in place of `HoldPattern` to reduce clutter. Since `myHoldPattern` does not hold its argument, unlike the bona fide `HoldPattern`, the evaluation will have happened by the time `x` is wrapped into `HoldPattern` for matching.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way by using `Verbatim`. Maybe it feels a bit less hacky.

```
{
 Cases[{1, a -> 2 b}, Verbatim[a -> 2 b]],
 Cases[{1, a -> 1/2 b}, Verbatim[a -> 1/2 b]],
 Cases[{1, a -> π b}, Verbatim[a -> π b]],
 Cases[{1, a -> c b}, Verbatim[a -> c b]]
 }
```

> {{a -> 2 b}, {a -> b/2}, {a -> b π}, {a -> b c}}