# NDSolve and Plotting

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate

So I am having an issue using `NDSolve` and plotting the function. So I have two different `NDSolve` calls in my plotting function. (They are technically the same, just have different names; but that can be changed back if at all possible because I want them to be the same.) But the second one is not working.

When I remove the plotting code from the `Manipulate` command, `Plot` works fine and outputs an answer. I just need the expanded form so that I can manipulate the variables (if there is a way around this, that would be great too!)

Here is what I have so far, any help would be appreciated as I have no idea why I am getting this error.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{
   (Evaluate[
     ReplaceAll[
      Paorta[t],
      NDSolve[
       {Paorta'[t] == 
         1/Caorta ((1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 10 - Paorta[t])/
            Piecewise[{{Ro, 
               1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 10 - Paorta[t] > 0}}, 
             x*Ro] - Paorta[t]/Rsystemic), Paorta[0] == 90},
       {Paorta[t]},
       {t, 0, 10}
       ]
      ]
     ]), (1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 
     10), (((1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 10) - 
      Evaluate[
       ReplaceAll[Pao[t], 
        NDSolve[{Pao'[t] == 
           1/Caorta ((1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 10 - Pao[t])/
              Piecewise[{{Ro, 
                 1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 10 - Pao[t] > 0}}, 
               x*Ro] - Pao[t]/Rsystemic), Pao[0] == 90}, {Pao[t]}, {t,
           0, 10}
         ]
        ]
       ])/Ro)},
  {t, 0, 10},
  ImageSize -> Large,
  PlotRange -> Full,
  PlotLegends -> {"Aortic Pressure", "Pressure in Left Ventricle", 
    "Flow"}
  ],
 {{Caorta, 1/.48}, 1, 6},
 {{Rsystemic, 3.1}, .1, 6},
 {{x, 8000}, 1, 10000},
 {{ω, 2 π}, π, 3 π},
 {{k, 110}, 60, 200},
 {{Ro, .01}, .007, .05}
 ]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: [(47907)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47907/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Pulled definition of `f` outside of `Manipulate` to avoid update issue pointed out by @MichaelE2

To keep the `Flow` from dominating the scale of the `Plot` and making it difficult to see the other two curves, I multiplied the `Flow` by `Ro`

```
f[t_, Caorta_, Rsystemic_, x_, \[Omega]_, k_, Ro_] :=
 Paorta[t] /. NDSolve[
    {Paorta'[t] ==
      1/Caorta ((1/2*k*(1 + Cos[\[Omega] t]) + 10 - Paorta[t])/
          Piecewise[
           {{Ro, 1/2*k*(1 + Cos[\[Omega] t]) + 10 - Paorta[t] > 0}},
           x*Ro] - Paorta[t]/Rsystemic),
     Paorta[0] == 90},
    {Paorta[t]}, {t, 0, 10}][[1]]

Manipulate[
 Plot[
  Evaluate[{f[t, Caorta, Rsystemic, x, \[Omega], k, Ro],
    1/2*k*(1 + Cos[\[Omega] t]) + 10,
    ((1/2*k*(1 + Cos[\[Omega] t]) + 10) -
      f[t, Caorta, Rsystemic, x, \[Omega], k, Ro])}],
  {t, 0, 10},
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  PlotRange -> Full,
  PlotLegends -> {"Aortic\nPressure",
    "Pressure in\nLeft Ventricle", "Ro*Flow"}],
 {{Control[{{Caorta, 1/.48}, 1, 6, Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
    Spacer[25],
    Control[{{Rsystemic, 3.1}, .1, 6, 
      Appearance -> "Labeled"}]}, {Control[{{x, 8000}, 1, 10000, 
      Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
    Spacer[25],
    Control[{{\[Omega], 2 \[Pi]}, \[Pi], 3 \[Pi], 
      Appearance -> "Labeled"}]}, {Control[{{k, 110}, 60, 200, 
      Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
    Spacer[25],
    Control[{{Ro, .01}, .007, .05, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]}} // 
  Grid]
```

[image]

Comment: @MichaelE2 - On my system it only updates when a control setting is changed. Perhaps you selected `AutoRun`.

Comment: The cell bracket is highlighted constantly.  When you set a down-value (`f[t_] = ...`) it triggers a dynamic update.  (V10.1, MacOS, in case it makes a difference. V9.0.1, too.)

Comment: I am also using v10.1 on a Mac. I see the cell bracket selected but nothing changes unless I move a slider.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm talking about this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/49257 -- Nothing in the displayed plot changes, but it is recomputed every time it finishes (like an infinite loop).  The highlighted cell bracket on a `Manipulate` indicates that the FE is waiting for the kernel to finish computing an update.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - edited to avoid this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Great. +1.  :) --

Answer (score 4):

You've got `Evaluate` in the wrong place.  It has to be of the form

```
Plot[Evaluate[stuff to plot...],...]
```

So this seems to work:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate@{
   (ReplaceAll[Paorta[t], 
      NDSolve[{Paorta'[t] == 
         1/Caorta ((1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 10 - Paorta[t])/
             Piecewise[{{Ro, 
                1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 10 - Paorta[t] > 0}}, 
              x*Ro] - Paorta[t]/Rsystemic), 
        Paorta[0] == 90}, {Paorta[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]]),
    (1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 10),
    (((1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 10) - 
        ReplaceAll[Pao[t], 
         NDSolve[{Pao'[t] == 
            1/Caorta ((1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 10 - Pao[t])/
                Piecewise[{{Ro, 1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 10 - Pao[t] > 0}}, 
                 x*Ro] - Pao[t]/Rsystemic), 
           Pao[0] == 90}, {Pao[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]])/Ro)}, {t, 0, 10}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> Full, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Aortic Pressure", "Pressure in Left Ventricle", "Flow"}],
 {{Caorta, 1/.48}, 1, 6},
 {{Rsystemic, 3.1}, .1, 6},
 {{x, 8000}, 1, 10000},
 {{ω, 2 π}, π, 3 π},
 {{k, 110}, 60, 200},
 {{Ro, .01}, .007, .05}]
```

`Plot` has the attribute [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html).  [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) overrides holding an argument exactly when it is the `Head` of the argument.  That's why the placement is important.

---

Re: Additional request for simplification.

Put the `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) outside the list of things to plot.  It will, after all, *replace all* instances of `Paorta`. :)

```
Manipulate[Plot[
  Evaluate[
   {Paorta[t],
    (1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 10),
    (((1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 10) - Paorta[t])/Ro)
   } /. NDSolve[{Paorta'[t] == 
       1/Caorta ((1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 10 - Paorta[t])/
           Piecewise[{{Ro, 1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 10 - Paorta[t] > 0}}, 
            x*Ro] - Paorta[t]/Rsystemic), 
      Paorta[0] == 90}, {Paorta[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
   ],
  {t, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> Full, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Aortic Pressure", "Pressure in Left Ventricle", "Flow"}],
 {{Caorta, 1/.48}, 1, 6},
 {{Rsystemic, 3.1}, .1, 6},
 {{x, 8000}, 1, 10000},
 {{ω, 2 π}, π, 3 π},
 {{k, 110}, 60, 200},
 {{Ro, .01}, .007, .05}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps cleaner

```
w[k_, ω_, t_] := 1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 10;

pnd = ParametricNDSolve[{
   Paorta'[t] == 1/Caorta ((w[k,ω,t] - Paorta@t)/ 
                 Piecewise[{{ρ, w[k,ω,t] - Paorta@t >0}}, x*ρ]- Paorta@t/Rsystemic), 
   Paorta[0] == 90},
   {Paorta}, {t, 0, 10}, {Caorta, k, ω, ρ, x, Rsystemic}]

Manipulate[
   Plot[
   {#,  w[k,ω,t], (w[k,ω,t] - #)/ρ} &@(Paorta/.pnd)[Caorta, k, ω, ρ, x, Rsystemic][t],
   {t, 0, 10},  Evaluated -> True,  PlotRange -> Full,
   PlotLegends -> {"Aortic Pressure", "Pressure in Left Ventricle", "Flow"}],
 {{Caorta, 1/.48}, 1, 6},
 {{Rsystemic, 3.1}, .1, 6},
 {{x, 8000}, 1, 10000},
 {{ω, 2 π}, π, 3 π},
 {{k, 110}, 60, 200},
 {{ρ, .01}, .007, .05}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]