# Should "counters" used in Do, Table, ... within Module be declared as local?

Tags: scoping

I have little to no understanding of how Mathematica handles scoping, so the question may seem a little bit funny.

What is the preferred way:

```
Test[] = Module[{},
   Do[Print["Hello ", i], {i, 5, 50, 5}];
   ];
Test[];
```

Or:

```
Test[] = Module[{i},
   Do[Print["Hello ", i], {i, 5, 50, 5}];
   ];
Test[];
```

Comment: First option is all you need. Mathematica handles scoping a couple of different ways. `Table`/`Do`/etc. create their own scope for an iterator, and I believe they use textual scoping just like `With` (but unlike `Block` and `Module`). This may help: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ScopingConstructs.html. In particular look at "Learning Resources".

Comment: One way to test such things is to use, and show, an explicit setting for your symbol. Try for example this small variation on your code: `Module[{i=-20}, Do[Print["Hello ", i], {i, 5, 50, 5}]; i]`. Notice that the `i` at the end is the `Module` variable and is not related to the `i` of the loop.

Comment: @d125q I've added an answer but there's a good chance someone will provide a better one or a good link to a previous answer. Worth waiting before you accept.

Comment: @mfvonh Actually `Table` & related functions use the same type of scoping as `Block` (not like `With`).  Try `Table[i = 1; Print[i], {i, 5}]`.

Comment: Also check the thirds heading [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/567/12)

Comment: for entertainment ask a "c" programmer what this does.. `i = {4, 5}; Do[Do[ Print[ i ] , {i, i}], {i, i}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One type of scoping uses "textual" replacement, meaning the symbolic layer of evaluation is bypassed. For example:

```
With[{i = 1}, SymbolName[Unevaluated[i]]]
```

[image]

> ```
> SymbolName[Unevaluated[1]]
> ```

This property of `With` makes it very handy sometimes, simply as a way to avoid evaluation where it is not wanted. I learned this myself in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46751/manipulating-slots-in-a-pure-function).

Compare that to:

```
Block[{i = 1}, SymbolName[Unevaluated[i]]]
```

> i

```
Module[{i = 1}, SymbolName[Unevaluated[i]]]
```

> i$24225

And turns out my comment above was inaccurate. `Table` does not use textual scoping:

```
Table[SymbolName[Unevaluated[i]], {i, 1, 1}]
```

> {i}