# A With and ContourPlot difficulty

Tags: plotting, evaluation

Consider:

```
sys = {u (1 - u + a v), r v (1 - v + b u)};
With[{a = 2, b = 3, r = 1},
 Evaluate[Thread[sys == {0, 0}]]]
```

Which gives the output:

```
(* {u (1 - u + 2 v) == 0, (1 + 3 u - v) v == 0} *)
```

Then, this works:

```
ContourPlot[{u (1 - u + 2 v) == 0, (1 + 3 u - v) v == 0},
 {u, -0.1, 2}, {v, -0.1, 2}]
```

Giving this image:

[image]

But why doesn't this work?

```
sys = {u (1 - u + a v), r v (1 - v + b u)};
With[{a = 2, b = 3, r = 1},
 ContourPlot[Evaluate[Thread[sys == {0, 0}]],
  {u, -0.1, 2}, {v, -0.1, 2}]]
```

I get a blank image with this code.

Comment: `s = a x;  With[{a = 1},  s]`

Comment: `s = a x;
Block[{a = 1},
 s]`

Comment: You may want to read this : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/193

Comment: @belisarius: If you post as answer, happily will delete mine...

Comment: @rasher Nah, I'm going to upvote yours. But only if you spell my name right :)

Comment: @belisarius: Doh. Fixed.

Comment: @rasher and beelzarus I propose closing this as a duplicate of [(46751)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46751/121) as I believe it is the same issue with `Evaluate`.  Also directly related to `ContourPlot`: [(6894)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6894/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard concur

Answer (score 3):

As noted by ***belisarius*** in the comment, you're running into scoping issues:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
sys = {u (1 - u + a v), r v (1 - v + b u)};
With[{a = 2, b = 3, r = 1}, 
    ContourPlot[
     Sow@Evaluate[Thread[sys == {0, 0}]], {u, -0.1, 2}, {v, -0.1, 
      2}]] // Reap // Last // Short[#, 5] &

ClearAll["Global`*"]
sys = {u (1 - u + a v), r v (1 - v + b u)};
Block[{a = 2, b = 3, r = 1}, 
    ContourPlot[
     Sow@Evaluate[Thread[sys == {0, 0}]], {u, -0.1, 2}, {v, -0.1, 
      2}]] // Reap // Last // Short[#, 5] &

(*

{{{-0.09985 (1.09985 -0.09985 a)==0,-0.09985 (1.09985 -0.09985 b) r==0},<<223>>,{2. (-1.+2. a)==0,2. (-1.+2. b) r==0}}}

{{False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,<<181>>,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False}}

*)
```

Note that with the `With`, your a,b, and r are never getting "in" there...

Comment: In plain English: basically, `With` and `Module` change the names of variables before the statements are evaluated.  When `With` starts, it only sees `sys`, not `a`, `b`, and `r`, so they are not replaced with their values.  You want `Block`, which changes the values of variables everywhere during execution (see `PrintTemporary[Dynamic[x]];Pause[1];Block[{x=1},Pause[1]];x`, for example).

Comment: @2012rcampion Using Block works, but how come when I look up the With command in the documentation, it says exactly this: "With[{x=x0, y=y0, ...}, expr] specifies that in expr occurrences of the symbols x, y, ... should be replaced with x0, y0, ...." Is it because what I have after the With starting point is not an expression?

Comment: @David Let's look at this minimal example: `a = b; With[{b = 1}, a]`.  When `With` does the replacement `b -> 1`, it looks at `expr`, which at this point is just `a`.  It says, "nope, I don't see any `b`s there, all done."  Then, **after the replacement takes place**, `expr` starts getting evaluated, at which point `a` is evaluated to `b` and returned.

Comment: @2012rcampion Ah, so it is because I have With[{a=2,b=3,r=1}, followed later by sys, which has no occurrences of a, b, or r, that nothing gets inserted and then things begin?

Comment: @David Exactly right, that's what rasher's code shows.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm not there yet (got a lot yet to learn), but these responses are helping me along the way.