# function includes integral in which limits are solutions to separate equations. Want to plot function

Tags: numerical-integration

Here is my code.

```
CMB[a_?NumericQ, lambda_?NumericQ] := 
 FindRoot[ns[i, lambda, a] - .96 == 0, {i, 15}]

END[a_?NumericQ, lambda_?NumericQ] := 
 FindRoot[eps[i, lambda, a] - 1 == 0, {i, 1}]

Ne[lambda_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] = 
 NIntegrate[
  V[i, lambda, a]/D[V[i, lambda, a], i], {i, Evaluate[END[a, lambda]],
    Evaluate[CMB[a, lambda]]}]
```

I am trying to get Mathematica to first evaluate the integral bounds, and then evaluate the integral at those bounds.  Is there any way to make it do that?

Comment: You are encouraged to post a complete, self-contained example rather than leaving mystery functions `ns`, `eps`, etc.

Comment: First, you probably want `:=` instead of `=` in your definition of `Ne`? How about using a scoping construct like `Module` where you first compute the limits as local variables and then pass those to the integration?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot evaluate your code due to missing functions but here is a shot in the dark:

```
CMB[a_?NumericQ, lambda_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[ns[i, lambda, a] - .96 == 0, {i, 15}]

END[a_?NumericQ, lambda_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[eps[i, lambda, a] - 1 == 0, {i, 1}]

Ne[lambda_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] :=
  With[{min = END[a, lambda], max = CMB[a, lambda]}, 
    NIntegrate[V[i, lambda, a]/D[V[i, lambda, a], i], {i, min, max}]
  ]
```

`Evaluate` must be the explicit head of an argument for it to have effect. See:

- [Manipulating slots in a pure function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46751/121)

Comment: I tried your code, and while it compiled without errors, when I tried to find what Ne was for a given lambda and a, it didn't compute.  Also, when i took the colon out of ':=' in the function declaration, I got the error  "i = END[a,lambda] is not a valid limit of integration. " Do you have any idea why this would be?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Seamus Providing a complete example will save us both time.  Glancing again at this `FindRoot` return results as `Rule` expressions rather than bare values, so you probably need something like `i /. FindRoot[ns[i, lambda, a] - .96 == 0, {i, 15}]` in the definitions.  I shall not attempt to debug this further without complete code.

Comment: By complete code, may I assume you are referring to the equations for V, ns, and eps?  If so, they depend on an interpolating function.  Is it possible to post a file of such a function here? Otherwise, the complete code will not be much use

Comment: Running this code, CMB[a_?NumericQ, lambda_?NumericQ] = 
 i /. FindRoot[ns[i, lambda, a] - .96 == 0, {i, 15}]

Comment: Mathematica returned these errors                                               FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {0.04 +(2. (\[Piecewise] <<1>>

))/\[Piecewise] <<1>>

-3. (Piecewise[{{<<2>>},{<<2>>},{<<2>>},{<<2>>},{<<2>>},{<<2>>}},0.]/Piecewise[{<<6>>},0.])^2.} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {i} = {15.}. >>ReplaceAll::reps: {FindRoot[ns[i,lambda,a]-0.96==0,{i,15}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>      Do you have any idea why the program is seeing the starting value for FindRoot as a list?

Comment: My apologies for the formatting.  I'm still learning how to type code in the stack exchange