# Setting options of expressions similar to using SetOptions on objects

Tags: options

**Introduction**

I often have the problem that in an expression, I want to change an option. If we are sure the option is not present, we could simply use `Append[expression, opt -> val]`. But sometimes such an expression is very long and it can be a bit of a pain to see if this option is already present.

*Example*

We have

```
Notebook[{Cell["hello", "Text"]}]
```

we want

```
Notebook[{Cell["hello", "Text"]}, Background -> LightGreen]
```

*Mathematica* has some built in functions for setting options. They are `SetOptions`, `Option` in combination with `Set` (which I think does the same thing as `SetOptions`) and `CurrentValue` in combination with `Set`. None of these seem to do what I want.

**Silly things I tried**

The fact that we can use `Options` with `Set` may sound promising, but although we can ask the value of an option in an expression, we cannot set it.

*Example*

```
kkkk:=f[2,q->c,z->x,zz->xx];
Options[kkkk]
Options[kkkk, q]
```

> ```
> {q -> c, z -> x, zz -> xx} 
> {q -> c}
> ```

But

```
Options[kkkk] = {q -> d, z -> x, zz -> xx}
```

gives an error and

```
Options[Unevaluated@kkkk] = {q -> d, z -> x, zz -> xx}
```

does something strange.

**Nice function**

So I have made my own function

```
setExpressionOptions[
  head_[
   a__,
   b : Longest[ OptionsPattern[], 1],
   Longest[(symb_ -> _) ..., 2],
   d : OptionsPattern[]
   ],
  symb_ -> val_
  ] := head[a, b, symb -> val, d]
```

*Examples of use*

```
setExpressionOptions[f[2, q -> b, z -> x, zz -> xx], q -> c]
```

> ```
>  f[2, q -> c, z -> x, zz -> xx]
> ```

```
setExpressionOptions[f[2, z -> x, zz -> xx], q -> c]
```

> ```
>  f[2, z -> x, zz -> xx, q -> c]
> ```

The function also works with `Unevaluated`

```
setExpressionOptions[Unevaluated[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]], PlotStyle -> Red]
```

> ```
>  (*a plot with a red line*)
> ```

Note that we really need `Unevaluated` here, otherwise the expression with head `Plot` evaluates to an expression with head `Graphics`, which does not work with `PlotStyle`.

**Possible extension**

We can define the function `setOptions` like this

```
setOptions[
  x_ /; MemberQ[{NotebookObject, CellObject, FrontEndObject, InputStream, 
     OutputStream, Symbol, String}, Head[Unevaluated@x]], y___
  ] := SetOptions[x, y]

setOptions[z___] := setExpressionOptions[z]
```

*Examples of use*

```
setOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Background -> LightGreen]
```

> ```
> (*makes the background LightGreen*)
> ```

```
setOptions[f[1], q -> r]
```

> ```
> f[1, q -> r]
> ```

**Question**

I like the functions quite a lot, but they could be better. It would be nice if we could set any number of options at once using `setExpressionOptions`.

*Example of desired evaluation*

```
setExpressionOptionsBetter[
 Notebook[{Cell["hello", "Text"]}, Background -> LightGreen],
 Background -> Cyan,
 DynamicUpdating -> True
 ]
```

> ```
>  Notebook[{Cell["hello", "Text"]}, Background -> Cyan, DynamicUpdating -> True]
> ```

Note that `SetOptions` works the same way; beyond position one there are any number of `Rule`s. That also makes integrating this case in `setOptions` easier.

Also I am sure I left out a lot of heads in the test in `setOptions`. The Q&A [How can I work out which functions work with SetOptions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/332/4330) sounded promising for making the list more complete, but I guess it is not helpful.

- Main question*: Can we add the additional functionality?

  - *sub Question 1*: Did I overlook anything and can this be done easier?
  - *sub Question 2*: Can this use of `Longest` lead to bad performance? (probably no)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another thought-provoking question Jacob, and sadly one I missed until today.  After only brief consideration I think perhaps what you want can be done more simply but I look forward to your critique of my proposal.

#### Assumptions:

- Exact preservation of the structure of option lists is not required
- The specific order of options is not significant
- Option rules may be safely evaluated

#### Basic Proposal

```
SetAttributes[setOpts, HoldFirst]

setOpts[head_[args___, opts : OptionsPattern[]], new__] := 
 First /@ GatherBy[Flatten@{new, opts}, First] /. {op___} :> head[args, op]
```

Test:

```
setOpts[f[1], q -> r]
```

> ```
> f[1, q -> r]
> ```

```
setOpts[
  f[2, q -> b, z -> x, {aa -> bb -> cc, foo :> bar}],
  z -> dog,
  a :> cat
]
```

> ```
> f[2, z -> dog, a :> cat, q -> b, aa -> bb -> cc, foo :> bar]
> ```

```
setOpts[Plot[Sinc@x, {x, 0, 10}], PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

#### Extended definition

To make the following case work an additional definition is required:

```
delay := Plot[Sinc@x, {x, 0, 10}]

setOpts[delay, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

> ```
> setOpts[delay, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]      (* failure *)
> ```

I shall use the same method I did for:

- [How to achieve Set+Part like behaviour in custom Set function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19897/how-to-achieve-setpart-like-behaviour-in-custom-set-function/19900#19900)
- [why set values in this way doesn't work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24495/why-set-values-in-this-way-doesnt-work/24558#24558)
- [Creating a Block from a list of rules](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31708/creating-a-block-from-a-list-of-rules/31711#31711)

This will require my `step` function from: [How do I evaluate only one step of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/334/how-do-i-evaluate-only-one-step-of-an-expression/1447#1447)

```
SetAttributes[step, HoldAll]

step[expr_] :=
  Module[{P},
    P = (P = Return[#, TraceScan] &) &;
    TraceScan[P, expr, TraceDepth -> 1]
  ]

setOpts[other_, new__] := step[other] /. _[x_] :> setOpts[x, new]
```

Now:

```
setOpts[delay, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

---

Related:

- [Consistent Plot Styles across multiple MMA files and data sets](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3247/121)
  (`setOpts` therein is not the same as the one here)

Comment: Thank you Mr.W, this is very nice! I like quite a few things about this. 1) in your examples you make explicit that we can have lists of options. I think I completely forgot this possibility and my function does not always work well here. 2) Your function works with `RuleDelayed`. 3) You can specify multiple options. 4) The order of non duplicate options is preserved and duplicates are removed. 5) Inserting new options at the start is more natural. On the flip side, I personally prefer a setup where `setOpts` does not have a hold attribute, analogous to `SetOptions` and friends.

Comment: @Jacob Thanks for your feedback, and the Accept.  Regarding your last point I hoped that my method would be a good hybrid: the second definition will cause it to evaluate until and *only* until the first definition matches.  Evaluation can be controlled by modifying the first pattern.  If you wish to return e.g. `setOpts["foo", 1 -> 2]` unevaluated that can done with a simple addition.  What behavior is lost in my approach that you would like to retain?  Perhaps it is possible.

Comment: @gpap I missed your comment. (Seeing a pattern?) Can you give a practical example of the kind of Options you wish to set and how it would work on these objects?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was using `f := Interpolation[list, InterpolationOrder -> 1]` and `g := setOpts[f, InterpolationOrder -> 4]` but your function actually works perfectly well.  I just mistyped `list = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 100}];` (so the transpose of what `Interpolation` likes) and the interpolation call was crashing my kernel (which I don't understand at all and is extremely annoying in its own right but nothing to do with your function). So, yeah, my bad and +1.

Answer (score 3):

I've written a similar function, but constrained to only add options that exist in [`Options`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Options.html).

```
changeOptions[wrapper_[args___, old:OptionsPattern[]], new:OptionsPattern[]] := With[
    {
    newopts = changedRules[Hold[old], {new}, options[wrapper]]
    },
    Replace[newopts, Hold[o___] :> wrapper[args, o]]
]

changeOptions[Hold[wrapper_[args___, old:OptionsPattern[]]], new:OptionsPattern[]] := With[
    {
    newopts = changedRules[Hold[old], {new}, options[wrapper]]
    },
    Replace[newopts, Hold[o___] :> Hold[wrapper[args, o]]]
]

changedRules[old_, new_, defaults_] := Module[{filtered, all},
    filtered = FilterRules[Flatten @ new, defaults];
    all = DeleteDuplicatesBy[
        Join[Hold@@filtered, Flatten[old, Infinity, List]],
        First
    ];
    Complement[all, Hold@@defaults]
]

options[Inactive[h_]] := Options[h]
options[h_] := Options[h]
```

Basic example:

```
changeOptions[
    Graphics[{Circle[]}, ImagePadding->3, PlotRange->{{0,2},{0,2}}],
    ImagePadding->None
] //InputForm
```

> Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}]}, ImagePadding -> None, 
>    PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}]

Example where defaults get removed:

```
changeOptions[
    Graphics[{Circle[]}, ImagePadding->3, PlotRange->{{0,2},{0,2}}],
    PlotRange->All
] //InputForm
```

> Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}]}, ImagePadding -> 3]

Example adding an invalid option:

```
changeOptions[
    Graphics[{Circle[]}, ImagePadding->None],
    foo->bar
]//InputForm
```

> Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}]}, ImagePadding -> None]

There is also support for held and inactive expressions. Example on a held expression (no evaluation leak):

```
changeOptions[
    Hold[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 1-1, Pi}, ImagePadding->10/2]],
    PlotRange->All
]
ReleaseHold@%
```

> Hold[Plot[Sin[x],{x,1-1,[Pi]},ImagePadding->10/2,PlotRange->All]]

[image]

Example on an [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) expression:

```
changeOptions[
    Inactive[Plot][Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, ImagePadding->All],
    ImagePadding->None
]
Activate@%
```

> Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,[Pi]},ImagePadding->None]

[image]

Comment: I am pleased again to be the first to upvote this.  I am curious, what do you think of my `step` and how I use it in my answer here?  I have to imagine that something like that has been considered within WRI.