# MapThread (or alternative) for adding fixed option

Tags: map, associations

I currently use `MapThread[f, {{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}]` for obtaining `{ f[a1, b1], f[a2, b2] }`.

Is there a version (or alternative) for obtaining `{ f[a1, b1, c], f[a2, b2, c] }`?

Basically I'd like to add a fixed option `c` (like `c1 -> c11`) to each invocation of `f`. How can it be done?

Comment: Somewhat related: [(38827)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38827/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `c` is common to all the entries, I would do this:

```
MapThread[f[##, c] &, {{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}}]

(* ==> {f[a1, b1, c] , f[a2, b2, c]} *)
```

Here the `##` stands for [`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SlotSequence.html) and accepts the pair of arguments fed into it by `Inner`, taken from the two `Lists`.

This is based on constructing a pure function (identified by the `&` at the end) that is used instead of `f`.

This also works in the special case that `c` is a rule:

```
MapThread[f[##, c1 -> c11] &, {{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}}]

(* ==> {f[a1, b1, c1 -> c11], f[a2, b2, c1 -> c11]} *)
```

Comment: This is close, but this `Inner` sums elements, wheras I need a list of elements. `f` is e.g. `HighlightImage`.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't looking carefully at what you wanted and over-thought the answer. Just keep using `MapThread`, not `Inner`.

Comment: Tx, now it's perfect.

Answer (score 3):

```
Thread[f[{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, c]]
(* {f[a1, b1, c], f[a2, b2, c]} *)

Thread[f[{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, c1 -> c11]]
(* {f[a1, b1, c1 -> c11], f[a2, b2, c1 -> c11]} *)
```

Comment: (+1) for the simplest approach.

Comment: If you try this with `HighlightImage` as `f` it will complain about expecting an image instead of a list of images.

Comment: @Drux - yes, the dimensions of the lists on which you work is important for `Thread`. It doesn't matter in your original example. But `MapThread` then would offer simpler control over the level at which the threading happens. It can be done with `Thread`, too, though.

Comment: Thank you @Jens. Drux, try `Unevaluated@HighlightImage` instead of `HighlightImage`.

Comment: @Drux maybe try `Thread[f[{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, c1 -> c11]] /. f-> HighlightImage` where `f` is a "dummy" symbol without any definition

Answer (score 0):

```
f[##, c] & @@@ (Transpose[{{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}}])
    (*{f[a1, b1, c], f[a2, b2, c]}*)
```