# Way to add a same option to multiple functions

Tags: options

Just wanna figure out if there is a decent way to add a same option to multiple functions simultaneously.

For example I have a series of `SoundNote`:

```
Sound[{SoundNote["D4", {0.4, 0.2}], SoundNote["G4", {0.6, 0.2}], SoundNote["B4", {0.8, 0.2}], SoundNote["D5", {1, 0.2}], SoundNote["A4", {1.2, 0.2}], SoundNote["E4", {1.4, 0.2}], SoundNote["G4", {1.6, 0.2}], SoundNote["A4", {1.8, 0.2}]}]
```

And now I want to add an option `SoundVolume -> 1/2` to the arguments of all functions in the list and make it like:

```
Sound[{SoundNote["D4", {0.4, 0.2},SoundVolume->1/2], SoundNote["G4", {0.6, 0.2},SoundVolume->1/2], SoundNote["B4", {0.8, 0.2},SoundVolume->1/2], SoundNote["D5", {1, 0.2},SoundVolume->1/2], SoundNote["A4", {1.2, 0.2},SoundVolume->1/2], SoundNote["E4", {1.4, 0.2},SoundVolume->1/2], SoundNote["G4", {1.6, 0.2},SoundVolume->1/2], SoundNote["A4", {1.8, 0.2},SoundVolume->1/2]}]
```

Is there any way to add the option instead of adding them one by one?

I've tried combining pure functions and `Append` like this:

```
Sound[Append[#,SoundVolume->1/2]& /@{SoundNote["D4", {0.4, 0.2}], SoundNote["G4", {0.6, 0.2}], SoundNote["B4", {0.8, 0.2}], SoundNote["D5", {1, 0.2}], SoundNote["A4", {1.2, 0.2}], SoundNote["E4", {1.4, 0.2}], SoundNote["G4", {1.6, 0.2}], SoundNote["A4", {1.8, 0.2}]}]
```

But it didn't work as it seems like the compiler sees `SoundVolume -> 1/2` as an option for `Append`.

Comment: Try a replacement rule: `list /. SoundNote[args__] :> SoundNote[args, SoundVolume -> 1/2]`.

Comment: In this specific case you should use `SoundVolume->1/2` as an option for `Sound` instead of an option for every single `SoundNote`.

Comment: You could also change the default option of `SoundNote` using [`SetOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOptions.html): `SetOptions[SoundNote, SoundVolume -> 1/2]`.

Comment: @Karsten, methinks your second comment is the best solution for this. Maybe expand on it a bit and make it an answer?

Comment: Related: [(38827)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38827/121)

Comment: cruiser, your code with `Append` works in version 10.1.0 under Windows.  Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 9.0 under Windows.

Answer (score 7):

The default option for `SoundNote` is

```
Options[SoundNote]
```

> `{SoundVolume -> 1}`

One can change the default using [`SetOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOptions.html)

```
SetOptions[SoundNote, SoundVolume -> 1/2]
```

Now all following `SoundNote` function calls will use the option `SoundVolume -> 1/2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Karsten and Guess. I think `SetOptions` is perfect for one needing to change the option globally while the replacement rule is good for local modifications.