# How to Clear variables represented as a list of strings?

Tags: string-manipulation, expression-manipulation, variable-definitions

Say I have a string list called `fullpara`

```
fullpara={"width", "long", "line", "distance"}
```

And there are corresponding variables to each string, and I want to `Clear` these variables

```
Clear[width, long, line, distance]
```

How to do it in a way to manipulate `fullpara` as a whole?

```
Clear@@(ToExpression/@fullpara)
```

obviously won't work because `ToExpression` will evaluate the variable that already has a value.

Comment: Related: "[Elegant manipulation of the variables list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322/280)."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`Clear` or `ClearAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Clear.html?q=Clear&lang=en) it is possible to provide symbols in form of regular expression (*limited*), in particular as string with exact symbol name.

```
Clear @@ {"width", "long", "line", "distance"}
```

---

Let's say there is no possibility to do that, one way would be:

```
Map[Clear, 
    ToExpression[{"width", "long", "line", "distance"}, InputForm, Hold], 
    {2}]; // ReleaseHold
```

Answer (score 9):

As Kuba notes you can use strings in `Clear` directly.  However having an understanding of how to work with such problems is helpful so here are some other ways.

A flexible approach is to use [`MakeExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MakeExpression.html) to convert strings to expressions in held form ([`HoldComplete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldComplete.html) specifically):

```
MakeExpression[fullpara]
```

> ```
> {HoldComplete[width], HoldComplete[long], HoldComplete[line], HoldComplete[distance]}
> ```

You can use [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Join.html) to put these in a single `HoldComplete` head and then Apply `Clear` or `ClearAll`:

```
Join @@ MakeExpression[fullpara]
```

> ```
> HoldComplete[width, long, line, distance]
> ```

```
Clear @@ Join @@ MakeExpression[fullpara]  (* clears Symbols *)
```

A more specific approach is to use the third argument of [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ToExpression.html) to `Clear` individual Symbols directly:

```
ToExpression[fullpara, StandardForm, Clear]; (* clears Symbols *)
```