# How to create a writable and clearable symbol?

Tags: symbols

I'm trying to create several symbols and assign values to them. Here's what currently appears to work:

```
Evaluate[Symbol["fdds" <> ToString[10]]] = 1
```

But there's then another problem: I can't clear it without explicitly saying `fdds10`, i.e. this code

```
Evaluate[Symbol["fdds" <> ToString[10]]] =.
```

as well as this

```
Clear[Evaluate[Symbol["fdds" <> ToString[10]]]]
```

give errors: the former gives

> Unset::usraw: Cannot unset raw object 1. >>

and the latter results in

> Clear::ssym: 1 is not a symbol or a string. >>

How do I create good easily manageable symbols?

<sub>PS: I know I could use something like `fdds[[10]]` here, but I'm interested in symbol-based solution.</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply `Clear` to the result of the expression generated by the string by using the optional third argument of [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ToExpression.html):

```
Evaluate[Symbol["fdds" <> ToString[10]]] = 1

(* ==> 1 *)

fdds10

(* ==> 1 *)

ToExpression["fdds" <> ToString[10], InputForm, Clear]

fdds10

(* ==> fdds10 *)
```

The third argument of `ToExpression` is `Clear` and wraps the expression `fdds10` before it is evaluated.

Comment: What would be the principal difference between `Symbol` and `ToExpression` here if the latter is used just with one argument? Could I just replace the former with the latter for the first assignment?

Comment: @Ruslan `ToExpression` is just a more high-level function that can act on expressions (even lists of expressions). The strings accepted by `Symbol` are limited to be valid symbol names. Because of this relationship, you can definitely use `ToExpression` in place of `Symbol` when you're sure you've constructed a valid symbol name string.

Answer (score 4):

`Clear` works on Strings exactly for such cases (I believe).
You must still evaluate `StringJoin`, my favorite way being `Apply`:

```
Clear @@ {"fdds" <> ToString[10]}
```

If this is all you need the question should be marked as a duplicate of:

- [How to Clear variables represented as a list of strings?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37755/121)

If we wish to make the question unique we can look at the more difficult case of `Unset` as applied to other kinds of definitions (those besides `OwnValues`).  For example:

```
Evaluate[Symbol["foo" <> ToString[10]][x_?Negative]] = 1;
Evaluate[Symbol["foo" <> ToString[10]][x_]] = 2;
```

How to `Unset` the first definition leaving the second in place?

These definitions work:

```
foo10[-3]
foo10[5]
```

> ```
> 1
> 2
> ```

However, due to the generic nature of the second definition this will evaluate in a way we do not want:

```
Evaluate[Symbol["foo" <> ToString[10]][x_?Negative]]   (* Evaluate merely for consistency *)
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

We can evaluate the Symbol `foo10`, since here it does have a value assigned, and insert it with `Function`:

```
Unset[#[x_?Negative]] & @ Symbol["foo" <> ToString[10]]

Definition[foo10]
```

> ```
> foo10[x_] = 2
> ```

---

Also related:

- [How can I test properties of a symbol from the string name without the symbol completely evaluating](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/197/121)
- [Assigning values to a list of variable names](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6511/121)
- [Elegant manipulation of the variables list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322/121)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand exactly what your application is, but looking at your usage I would guess, you don't want `fdds[[10]]` as you would need to initialize an array?

```
fdds[[10]] // FullForm
```

> ```
> Part[fdds,10]
> ```

In this case you could use `fdds[10]`. Note that `[[]]` is not `[]` and you do not need to initialize anything.

```
fdds[10] // FullForm
```

> ```
> fdds[10]
> ```

```
fdds[5] = 1;
fdds[10] = 2;
fdds // Definition
```

> ```
> fdds[5]=1
> fdds[10]=2
> ```

```
Unset[fdds[10]]
fdds // Definition
```

> ```
> fdds[5] = 1
> ```

**edit:** Now I know, this is answer is not suitable for OPs case, but maybe the answer helps someone new to *Mathematica* to avoid messy method.

Comment: Please note the PS part of the question, which has been there since the very beginning. I do know I can do this like an array, but I'm interested in symbol-based approach.

Comment: @Rusian It is not an array. `[]` is not `[[]]`. And I don't know what do you mean by "symbol-based". Do you need, that the `Head` is a `Symbol`? Could you tell why?

Comment: I was just interested in creating a usable symbols. I'm well aware of the possibility to use hash maps like `fdds[anything]=1`.

Comment: @Ruslan. Ok. Now you told we words. I hope the answer still helps someone else to avoid messy methods.