# Clearing a global variable from inside a Module

Tags: programming, evaluation, variable-definitions

This is a highly simplified version of a initialization problem I have with
a complicated program with many (about 100) modules.

If one enters: `X=42; Clear[X];` the `X` value is removed. Fine.
Now consider 3 simple modules:

```
ClearMyX0[]:=Module[{}, Clear[X]];

ClearMyX1[]:=Module[{}, s=Symbol["X"]; Clear[s]];

ClearMyX2[]:=Module[{}, Clear["X"] ];
```

and try

```
X=42; ClearMyX0[]; X=42; ClearMyX1[]; X=42; ClearMyX2[];
```

(Print statements removed for brevity.) I find that `ClearMyX0` works as expected. `ClearMyX2` also works but `ClearMyX1` does not. I have no idea why - my presumption about those two was the opposite.

So far I have not seen web documentation explaining that behavior. Please give me a reference.

Comment: after `s = Symbol["X"];` there is not infomation about `X` in `s`, only the value is assigned.

Comment: Note that `Clear` is `HoldAll`. So `Clear[s]` means quite literally what it says. @Kuba's comment applies as well, of course. There is actually no renaming going on in any of these examples (I thought that could have been your problem at first glance), so I think there is nothing unexpected here.

Comment: You should be aware of the fact that a `Module` without a local variable doesn't change anything to what you are trying to do. If you want to remove a symbol whose name is stored in a variable as a string, you could use: `ClearMyX3[] := Module[{s}, s = "X"; Clear[Evaluate@s]]`. (note that I have localized `s`, so in that  case the `Module` isn't useless which is what you probably want to do in the long term and it shows that this will also work...). In general I would never suggest to write code which needs to clear globals, can you explain why you think you need this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting `Clear[x]` to clear definitions of `x`, don't expect anything more from `Clear[s]`.

So you can go with:

```
X = 5; s = "X"; Clear[#] &@s
X
```

> X

Or, as pointed by Albert Retey, with `Clear[Evaluate@s]`.

Maybe you don't want to use strings, then:

```
X = 5; s = ToExpression["X", StandardForm, Unevaluated];

Clear[#] &@s
X
```

works too. Some additional ways and comments can be found in Mr. Wizard's answer in: [How to Clear variables represented as a list of strings?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37809/5478)