# Generate assignment code to symbols from string

Tags: evaluation, code-generation, meta-programming

I want the function to take in string, then assign a value to its corresponding symbol. An implementation using `ToExpression` is

```
mySet[str_String, val_] := 
ToExpression["Set[" <> str <> "," <> ToString[val] <> "]"]
```

How can I do it **without** `ToExpression`? **I wonder how this can be done with purely evaluation control.**

I have read the following posts:
[Generating assignments and transforming code inside held forms when generating code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103263/generating-assignments-and-transforming-code-inside-holding-forms-when-generatin)

[How do I evaluate only one step of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/334/how-do-i-evaluate-only-one-step-of-an-expression?lq=1)

I think the main problem is to evaluate `Symbol["x"]` partially to `x`(it can have `OwnValues`), which can't be achieved with first post's code; and second post's code is indeed returning a `HoldForm` expression, leaving me generally the same problem.

Comment: @Kuba what if I want to avoid the use of `ToExpression`

Comment: I don;t think you can, since you are starting with a string and `Symbol[]` can't handle symbols with values: `x = 5; Symbol["x"]`

Comment: @Kuba I am also curious if there is any method that can temporarily suspend the `OwnValues` of that symbol

Comment: @Kuba yes, I ended up with the same problem with `Block`

Comment: The problem is, even if you want to avoid `ToExpression` during assignment you have to make MMA understand `"x"` is `x` which means you have to convert it to an expression (held or not) at some point, and whether you will use something different from `ToExpression` doesn't matter, you will effectively do this. E.g. you can export "x" as a text file and import/get as expression, but deeper this will still be *ToExpression*.

Comment: @Kuba I see, it seems I don't have a correct knowledge of the convention when to use `ToExpression`. I will think about it.

Comment: I'm encouraging you to not trust me in 100% :) I'm learning mma each day, even basic things. ps. why do you want to avoid `ToExpression`?

Comment: @Kuba Thank you very much for your patience. When I do code generation, I see people prefer to play a lot with evaluation control and tricks, but I see no experienced programmer write `ToExpression` code like what I wrote in the question, though it is easier to understand/write and it works. I believe there must be some other reason than it's ugly(but I don't know the reason, so I simply avoided the use of `ToExpression` as I can).

Comment: I suppose the it's not `ToExpression` but a working with Strings what is not popular. Not only it's ugly but `"x"` misses current `$Context` for example.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6234701/618728) is the oldest question on Stack Exchange I know that relates to this problem, and Leonid's answer serves as the foundation for my own methods below.

Comment: Just for record,`my[a_,b_]:=ToExpression[TemplateApply["Set[``,``]",{a,b}]]`.Of course,you don't like `ToExpression`. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you referenced [How do I evaluate only one step of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/334/121) I might use:

```
(* step loaded from referenced Q&A *)

mySet[str_String, val_] := step @ Symbol[str] /. _[s_Symbol] :> (s = val)
```

Now:

```
x = 5;

mySet["x", 7];

x
```

> ```
> 7
> ```

(This also makes use of [Injecting a sequence of expressions into a held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1929/injecting-a-sequence-of-expressions-into-a-held-expression/1937#1937).)

For clarity the above is trying to answer in what I think is the spirit of your question.
Pragmatically I usually<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/197/121)[(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2651/121)[(3)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37755/121)</sup> use [`MakeExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeExpression.html), see e.g. my answer to the closely related:

- [How do you programatically load data into symbols?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783/121)

  (Also make special note of Kuba's use of `RawBoxes`)

Comment: Wow this is really clever!

Comment: While `MakeExpression` is not exactly `ToExpression` I feel like it's the same in this context. Nontheless `P` function is mindblowing!

Comment: @Kuba That's why I did not use `MakeExpression` in my original answer, but I thought it best to include for reference, as well as your own lovely `RawBoxes` example.  You are referring to the code of my `step` function?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, but I should have said mind-cracking or something because I still don't fully understand what's happening and how had you figured it out :)

Comment: @Kuba I will admit that despite its brevity that code took a lot of thinking on my part!  The `(P = (P =` thing is self-redefinition a la [(2676)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2676/121) to avoid spitting out the verbatim unevaluated expression.  (By the way I just rewrote my answer to keep it more focused, yet hopefully reference what needs referencing for completeness.  Let me know if you agree.)