# Assigining values after the Apply operator

Tags: assignment

I am writing a script where I need many variables and for ease of usage I denote them as `f[k,l,m,n]`. I create a list of 4-tuples with the integers I need and I call these values using `f@@{k,l,m,n}`.

My problem is that I also need to assign values but writing `f@@{k,l,m,n}=1` returns an error, declaring that the Tag Apply is protected. Is there any way to overcome this or do I need to assign my values using `f[k,l,m,n]=1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Set` have `HoldFirst` Attribute, `f @@ {k, l, m, n}` will not be evaluated. You can do

```
Evaluate[f @@ {k, l, m, n}] = 1
```

Comment: @tst You can assign like `Do[Set[Evaluate[f @@ t], g[t]], {t, tuples}]` in a loop, whatever the values `g` are ...

Comment: I dare you to do that twice :)

Comment: @Kuba it reminded me of what we discussed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116512/generate-assignment-code-to-symbols-from-string), OP would have to come to your solution if he has to do it twice:)

Comment: @Kuba Or this: `TraceScan[# /. _[expr_] :> Unset[expr] &, f @@ {k, l, m, n}] // Quiet` (but this is actually terrible)