# Apply Clear puzzle

Tags: list-manipulation, symbols, clear

This is OK

```
foo=1; bar=2;
Clear[foo,bar]
```

But this is not

```
foo=1; bar=2;
Clear@@{foo,bar}
```

> Clear::ssym: 1 is not a symbol.
>   Clear::ssym: 2 is not a symbol.

So how do you [`Clear`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clear.html) a list of symbols?

I understand that clearing a list of strings that name those symbols, as in [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37755/how-to-clear-variables-represented-as-a-list-of-strings) is possible. But that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: In that case, just use `SetAttributes[clear, HoldAll]; clear[{a__}] := Clear[a]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you have an unevaluated list of symbols that values, but you can use [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html) to keep it that way:

```
foo = 1; bar = 2;
Clear @@ Unevaluated@{foo, bar}
```

Comment: This is BY FAR the best answer to my question.

Answer (score 8):

I would store a list of the variable symbol names instead of the symbols:

```
vlist = {"foo", "bar"};

foo = 1; bar = 2;
Clear @@ vlist

foo
bar
```

> foo
>
> bar

If you are copy/pasting the list of symbol names, then I think the following function would be simplest:

```
SetAttributes[clear, HoldAll]
clear[{a__}] := Clear[a]

x=2; y=2; z=2;
clear[{x, y, z}]

{x, y, z}
```

> {x, y, z}

Comment: The problem is that  what I want to delete is a list of symbols, not a list of names.

Comment: This isn't the best answer to my question, even though it got the most up votes.

Answer (score 7):

Note that this is happening in your code because by the time Clear gets to the variables, List (`{}`) has evaluated them and Clear tries to operate on `1` and `2`, which is of course nonsense.

Consider the clearList function here:

```
In[1]:= x = y = z = 2;

In[2]:= clearList[lis_List] := 
 ReleaseHold[Map[Clear, HoldComplete[lis], {2}]]
SetAttributes[clearList, HoldFirst]

In[5]:= {x, y, z}

Out[5]= {2, 2, 2}

In[6]:= clearList[{x, y, z}]

Out[6]= {Null, Null, Null}

In[7]:= {x, y, z}

Out[7]= {x, y, z}
```

This is what I use, there may be better ways to do it.

Comment: I understood why, I just didn't know how to fix it. Thanks for the excellent answer.

Comment: I’d like to add that Carl gave a more succinct version of this in the comments above. Same effect though.