# HoldFirst and Hold expression as argument

Tags: associations, assignment, hold

I store a reference to the association in a held expression in a variable:

```
a=<||>;
b=Hold[a];
```

And in the code, I want to do manipulations with the original variable `a` including using methods that have `HoldFirst` attribute.

```
AssociateTo[b,"test"->1];
(* this obviously does not work *)

AssociateTo[ReleaseHold@b,"test"->1];
(* this does not either *)
```

Question is, how do I use `b` in `AssociateTo[]` to associate the value to the original globally-defined `a` association?

To clarify, my use case is that I store data in a nested Association stored as `CloudExpression` and create references ("indexes") of the values inside this association as `Hold[]` constructs. This works perfectly fine until I get to use the `HoldFirst`-set methods.

**Update**:

I was able to implement the desired behaviour using the ugly

```
AssociateToHold[assoc_,data_]:=
  ReleaseHold@
    Replace[
      Hold[AssociateTo[where,what]]/.
        {HoldPattern[where]->Unevaluated[assoc],HoldPattern[what]->data},
      Hold[x_]:>x,{2}
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
associateToHold[Hold[v_], data_] := AssociateTo[v, data]

associateToHold[b, "test" -> 1]

(* <| "test" -> 1 |> *)

a

(* <| "test" -> 1 |> *)
```

We could do the same thing inline:

```
b /. _[v_] :> AssociateTo[v, "test" -> 1]
```

... or use a function with `HoldFirst`:

```
Function[Null, AssociateTo[#, "test" -> 1], HoldFirst] @@ b
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is a variation of [Elegant manipulation of the variables list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322/121).
The `bump` function I defined therein can be used here, e.g.

```
AssociateTo[bump[b, 1], "test" -> 1];

a
```

> ```
> <|"test" -> 1|>
> ```

If you feel daring you can overload the system function like this:

```
Unprotect[AssociateTo];

AssociateTo[s_Symbol, defs_] /;
  MatchQ[OwnValues[s], {_ :> Hold[_Symbol]}] :=
    s /. Hold[ss_] :> AssociateTo[ss, defs]
```

Now this works as desired:

```
AssociateTo[b, "test" -> 1]
```

Reference: [Injecting a sequence of expressions into a held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1929/121)