# Why this list has a length of 1?

Tags: core-language, hold

Here is the code :

```
bb = HoldForm[{aa[1], bbb[2], cc[3], dd[4]}]
```

it returns :

```
{aa[1], bbb[2], cc[3], dd[4]}
```

Which is what I expect.

But when I do :

```
Length[bb]
```

It returns

```
1
```

Why ?? Why doesn't it return 4?

The `aa`, `bbb`, `cc`, `dd` are functions that I want to keep in an unevaluated form.

Comment: try `Length[bb[[1]]]` to get 4. Check `Head[bb]`  and `FullForm[bb]` to see why you are getting `1`.

Comment: The head is a HoldForm and indeed, Length[bb[[1]]=4. But why in the result the HoldForm disappears ?

Comment: Strabuck, that's what `HoldForm` does. [HoldForm >> Details:](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldForm.html) _HoldForm allows you to **see the output form of an expression** without evaluating the expression._

Comment: @kglr I edited my message. If I understand it is just a matter of visualisation ? If I want to "really" unevaluate the things inside because I want to keep it in a "factorised" form before sending it to a function it will not work ?

Comment: Starbuck, perhaps, [Inactivate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html) is what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding "*The aa, bbb,cc,dd are functions that I want to keep in an unevaluated form*":

If you have version 10 or a newer version, [Inactivate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html) is useful for this purpose:

```
aa = # + 1 &;
bbb = #^2 &;
bb2 = Inactivate[{aa[1], bbb[2], cc[3], dd[4]}]
```

> [image]

```
Length @ bb2
```

> 4

```
TreeForm @ bb2
```

[image]

```
bb2[[2]]
```

> [image]

```
bb2[[2]]//Activate
```

> 4

Comment: Yeaaah exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 8):

The expression `bb` has only one leaf, a `List`:

```
bb = HoldForm[{aa[1], bbb[2], cc[3], dd[4]}];

bb // TreeForm
```

[image]

If you want to hold separate elements that will be individually manipulated perhaps:

```
newbb = Thread[bb];

newbb // TreeForm
```

[image]

The `Length` of `newbb` is `4`.

Possibly of interest:

- [Elegant manipulation of the variables list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322/121)