# HoldFirst being overridden by Activate

Tags: functions, evaluation, attributes

So here's the problem
`a=1;a=2`
works because of the `HoldFirst` attribute of `Set`, so that it does not become `1=2`
But `a=1;Activate[Inactivate[a=2]]` does not because the attributes of `Set` is lost during `Inactivate`. So how do I avoid this problem?

**Update**
So I've read the answers and it was a brilliant solution. The reason for my use of `Inactivate` is is meta-programming, where the symbols are `Inactive` during the construction to avoid messing everything up. But I used `Set` in the code so that's why I encountered this problem.

Comment: Any solution will probably include a lot of trickery - the problem is that the only composite head that can have attributes is `Function[...]`, but there is no way to prevent expressions of the form `Function[...][...]` from evaluating. You could of course use a different way to inactivate the heads, but making them composite seems like the best way if one wants to preserve the structure of the expression.

Comment: One could argue that it is exactly what should be expected to happen since you are inactivating `Set` so it behaves as it wasn't there. If you don't wan't it, what do you expect from `Inactivate`?

Comment: maybe `Activate[Inactivate[Inactive[a] = 2]]`?

Comment: Maybe you can use `Hold` and `ReleaseHold`?

Comment: @Kuba I'm guessing that the OP is looking for a variation of `Inactive[Set]` that has the `HoldFirst` attribute of `Set`. But since `Inactive[Set]` is a composite head, it cannot have attributes, as far as I know.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to achieve, maybe this helps? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10322/elegant-manipulation-of-the-variables-list

Comment: @SjoerdSmit maybe, we need more info because maybe OP does not need `Inactive` at all but some sort of guidance for Hold family of functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Edit: As noted in the comments, you're probably better off using `Hold`,`ReleaseHold` etc. to solve your problem, since `Inactivate` was never designed for this use case. Having said that, below you'll find one possible attempt to replicate the desired behaviour as closely as possible]

## The goal

For this answer, I'll try to address the following requirements for a new function `myInactivate`:

- `myInactivate` should replicate the behaviour of `Inactivate` for cases where there are no `Hold` attributes at play. This includes:

  - Nice typesetting
  - Localized inactivation in the sense that parts are inactivated separately
  - A way to activate only parts again (see possible extensions below)
- Inactivated symbols should still have the same `Hold` attributes as the original symbol

## Examples

You can find the code for `myInactivate`,`myActivate`, etc. at the end of the answer.

`myInactivate` can be used just like `Inactivate`:

```
a = 1;
myInactivate[a = 2]
(* myInactive[Set][a, 2] *)

myActivate[%]
(* 2 *)
```

It also supports the typesetting of `Inactive` expressions:

```
myInactivate[Sum[f[a = 2, z], {n, 1, 2}]]
```

[image]

You can filter out all inactive heads using `myInactiveQ`:

```
myInactivate[Sum[f[a = 2, z], {n, 1, 2}]] // 
 Cases[#, _?myInactiveQ, All, Heads -> True] &
(* {myInactive[Sum], myInactive[f], myInactive[Set]} *)
```

You can also manually create inactive symbols using `myInactive`:

```
myInactive[Set][a, 2]
```

[image]

## Possible extensions

To make something like this really something with more control than `Hold` and related functions, one would need to implement the two argument forms of `Inactivate` and `Activate` (i.e. filtering of what gets inactivated). This would then allow for selective inactivation, something that is difficult to achieve with `Hold` and friends.

## How it works

As noted in the comments, composite heads (e.g. `Inactive[Set]`) are out, as they can't have any attributes. So the only thing we can to is to replace the heads with a new, inert symbol. This is exactly what `myInactive` does (let `sym` be the symbol to inactivate):

- If not already done, it creates a new symbol (e.g. `inactivesym`), with the same attributes as `sym` (except `Protected` and `Locked`, for obvious reasons).
- It adds the new symbol `inactivesym` to `inactSymbols`, the replacement list to revert inactivation.
- It adds a typesetting rule to typeset `inactivesym[...]` as `Inactive[sym][...]` (wrapped in an `InterpretationBox`, to ensure that the output can be copied)
- It adds a typesetting rule to typeset `inactivesym` as `myInactive[sym]`
- It marks `inactivesym` as `myInactiveQ`

You'll also notice the special casing of `List` and `Rule`: Apparently, `Inactivate` doesn't touch some inert heads such as `List` and `Rule`, so I've added them here as well.

## Code

```
inactSymbols = <||>;

Attributes[myInactiveQ] = {HoldFirst};
myInactiveQ[_] := False

Attributes[myInactive] = {HoldFirst};
myInactive[h_] := myInactive[h] = With[
   {s = Unique["inact" <> SymbolName@Unevaluated@h]},
   Attributes[s] = Complement[Attributes[h], {Protected, Locked}];
   MakeBoxes[s[args___], frm_] ^:= With[
     {b = MakeBoxes[Inactive[h][args], frm]},
     InterpretationBox[b, s[args]]
     ];
   AppendTo[inactSymbols, s -> h];
   MakeBoxes[s, frm_] ^:= MakeBoxes[myInactive[h], frm];
   myInactiveQ[s] ^= True;
   s
   ]
myInactive[s_?myInactiveQ] := s
myInactive[s : List | Rule] := s

Attributes[myInactivate] = {HoldFirst};
myInactivate[expr_] := Replace[
  Unevaluated@expr,
  {
   i : HoldPattern[myInactive[h_][args___]] :> i,
   h_Symbol[args___] :> With[
     {in = myInactive[h]},
     in[args] /; True
     ]
   },
  All
  ]

myActivate[expr_] := expr /. inactSymbols
```

Comment: What features are you trying to address in general? Can you update OP to make it clear what do we aim for? One could ask why not `HoldForm` + `ReleaseHold`.

Comment: @Kuba I have no idea what OP wants to do with this - I agree that in general, `Hold` and friends are probably more suited, this is just an attempt to provide a solution if OP really wants something in the style of `Inactivate`.

Comment: Then could you edit your answer and outline features that you had in mind?

Comment: @Kuba: Do the additions address your concerns?

Comment: Yep, thank you.

Comment: Works really well, although my poor understanding in these functions disabled me from fully understanding how your code works...

Comment: @t-smart If you can point out which parts are unclear, I can try to explain them in more detail. (Also, while I'm glad that this works for you, keep in mind that there might still be a more straightforward solution using `Hold`)

Comment: @LukasLang Thanks, but I think I'd try and read the documentation first... as I've never used these functions before