# Associate the elements of a table

Tags: list-manipulation, assignment

I have a table form as:

```
table = {{a, 6}, {b, ff}, {c, 2}}
```

I want to associate the first element of each pair from the table to the second element of the pair as in:

```
a=6, b=ff, c=2.
```

I want the parameters a,b,c  to be recognized throughout the program with assigned values. Doing as below, everything is perfect:

```
a := 6;
a^2 + 5
Clear[a]
Out[2] 41
```

But in the example below, I failed:

```
Clear[table, a, b, c]
table = {{a, 6}, {b, ff}, {c, 2}}
z = table[[1, 1]]
z := table[[1, 2]]
a^2 + 5

Out[4]  {{a, 6}, {b, ff}, {c, 2}}
Out[5]  a
Out[6]  5 + a^2
```

Why this fail?

Comment: I don't see why it should work. One way to assign the second element to the first element is `Set @@@ {{a, 6}, {b, ff}, {c, 2}}`. Now `a` returns `6`, `b` returns `ff` and so on. Maybe if you explain why you think it should work, someone could explain why it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

This may be considered a duplicate of [Assign the results from a Solve to variable(s)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6669/121) which despite different formulation shares the same shortest answer:

```
Set @@@ {{a, 6}, {b, ff}, {c, 2}}
```

This may also be related to [Reassign values to symbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/280/121) if you expect to be able to make different assignments to the same Symbols in the same way.  I mean that if you attempt a second series of assignments in the same manner it will not work:

```
Set @@@ {{a, 5}, {b, Pi}, {c, 7/3}}
```

> Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object 6. >>
>
> Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object 2. >>

An alternative form that will work requires keeping the assignment pairs in `Hold`:

```
List @@ Set @@@ Hold[{a, 5}, {b, Pi}, {c, 7/3}];

{a, b, c}
```

> ```
> {5, π, 7/3}
> ```

Also related:

- [Assigning values to a list of variable names](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6511/121)
- [How do you programatically load data into symbols?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783/121)
- [Elegant manipulation of the variables list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322/121)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll keep in mind the problems that arise from reassign symbols.

Answer (score 2):

`SetDelayed` has attribute `HoldAll`, so your `z := table[[1, 2]]` assigns the righthand-side to `z` instead of `a`. If you really insist on doing your assignment in this programmatic way, use `Evaluate` and `Set`:

```
Clear[table, a, b, c]
table = {{a, 6}, {b, ff}, {c, 2}}

z = table[[1, 1]]
Evaluate[z] = table[[1, 2]]
```

Or `SetDelayed`, but then expect `a` to be recalculated every time in `table` which leads to a circular definition of `a`, causing infinite recursion. Hence the `Quiet`:

```
Clear[table, a, b, c]
table = {{a, 6}, {b, ff}, {c, 2}}

z = table[[1, 1]]
Evaluate[z] := Quiet@table[[1, 2]]
```

A more elegant way (as pointed out by Anon) is to use `Set` and `Apply`:

```
Clear[table, a, b, c];
table = {{a, 6}, {b, ff}, {c, 2}};
Set @@@ table
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your proposed solution which helped me completely. Very elegant indeed, with Set and Apply