# Attempting to modify parts of a multi-level association in-place

Tags: associations

Generate a simple two-level association

```
In[1]:= m2 = <|"M" -> <|1 -> {1, 2, 3}, 2 -> {2, 3}|>, "F" -> <|1 -> {}, 2 -> {}|>|>

Out[1]= <|M-><|1->{1,2,3},2->{2,3}|>,F-><|1->{},2->{}|>|>
```

Show that `m2["M"]` is an L-value (assignable) of type association

```
In[2]:= Head[m2["M"]]

Out[2]= Association

In[3]:= m2["M"] = <|1 -> {1}, 2 -> {1, 2}|>; m2

Out[3]= <|M-><|1->{1},2->{1,2}|>,F-><|1->{},2->{}|>|>
```

AssociateTo is `HoldFirst`, it should pass `m2["M"]` unevaluated to be treated as an L-value

```
In[4]:= Attributes[AssociateTo]

Out[4]= {HoldFirst, Protected}

In[5]:= AssociateTo[m2["M"], "b" -> 3]; m2
```

> During evaluation of In[5]:= AssociateTo::rvalue: m2(M) is not a variable with a value, so its value cannot be changed. >>

```
Out[5]= <|M-><|1->{1},2->{1,2}|>,F-><|1->{},2->{}|>|>
```

I don't understand exactly why this fails.  I am trying to do an in-place modification of the bottom level of a nested association.  I was hoping to use the ideas of [Use `Scan` vs. `Map`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/280/reassign-values-to-symbols) to accomplish this, but it appears that `AssociateTo` is behaving in an unexpected way. Is there a way to accomplish this, perhaps using "Replacing parts of held expression?".

Comment: Associations are treated as atomic under most operations and, therefore, can not be modified in-place. Your concept of an association as kind of structure as found in procedure languages is, unfortunately for you, wrong.

Comment: Note that this works: `AssociateTo[m2[["M"]], "b" -> 3]; m2`. Strongly related discussion can be found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55494/changing-values-in-an-association-using-map).

Comment: @m_goldberg Your statement is incorrect. Associations are given certain degree of (user-level) mutability, when stored in a symbol, just as lists are.  Check out my answer I linked to, in the previous comment, for a longer discussion of this.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes - this looks like a perfectly legitimate question to me.

Comment: Not sure why the close votes either. Did someone have a bad day today?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin. `AtomQ` on a association returns `True`.

Comment: @m_goldberg *`AtomQ` on a association returns `True`* -  which is rather unfortunate, and this was done mostly to forbid pattern-matching inside associations like other expressions, and also to avoid making `Association` explicitly `HoldAllComplete`. But I didn't mean this fact, but the other things you stated about mutability and in-place modifications. Associations are clearly not atomic for part extraction and modifications, *despite* returning `True` on  `AtomQ`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin. I view associations as being more like complex numbers than like lists in terms of mutability. Perhaps the analogy is ill-conceived, but nothing I've read has so far convinced me to discard it.

Comment: @m_goldberg *" but nothing I've read has so far convinced me to discard it."* - well, how about in-place modifications? Like the one with `Set` on the top of this post, which works perfectly. Or many more examples, both in the docs and in my post I linked above. In my view, they are much closer to lists (arrays), than to complex numbers - they have similar mutability properties, and both are indexed containers of elements.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks for the reference, very well written.

Comment: @m_goldberg In fact, there are even much simpler pieces of evidence here, e.g. how `Map` and similar functions work on assocs.

Comment: @JJM Glad if that was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can create/assign a key/value directly by using the resetting values syntax.

```
m2 = <|"M" -> <|1 -> {1, 2, 3}, 2 -> {2, 3}|>, "F" -> <|1 -> {}, 2 -> {}|>|>;

m2["M"]["b"] = 3;

m2
(* <|"M" -> <|1 -> {1, 2, 3}, 2 -> {2, 3}, "b" -> 3|>, "F" -> <|1 -> {}, 2 -> {}|>|> *)
```

This is the last example case in the *Basic Examples* subsection of the **Examples** section of the [Association documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html).

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks.  I included an example of using Set in this way in my original question.  My issue was with simulated pass by reference for expressions like m2["M"][1].  Leonid's linked article cleared up the matter for me.

Comment: I see your question above uses 'AssociateTo'  to add '"b"'. I am showing how you don't need to call any functions to create '"b"'' in place.