# How can I assign many values each to a different variable?

Tags: core-language, assignment

How can I assign many values each to a different variable?

For example, I want to set $a = f(1),\,b = f(2),\,c = f(3),\,\dots,\,z = f(26)$ (generally more variables than these). How can I do this using a loop statement? I have tried to put the letters in a matrix, then give values to the matrix elements, but my letters didn't get any values.

Comment: Does this fit your needs? [How do you programatically load data into symbols?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783/5478)

Comment: Why do you not want to just use `Table`? All the fancy alternatives may be completely unnecessary unless you provide a reason why `Table` isn't useful to you.

Comment: These may be even better duplicates but I already voted: [(280)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/280/121), [(6511)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6511/121)

Answer (score 8):

First of all, please note that coding this way in Mathematica is asking for trouble. Use of (lots of) mutable variables is strongly discouraged. The following will show you why:

1. Clearing all symbols `a` to `z` in case they have been assigned some values is not trivial to do automatically in one go as it necessitates the manipulation of the *order of standard evaluation* with `Unevaluated` or some variety of the `Hold`-family of functions.

   ```
   a = 1 (* Assigns the value 1 to the symbol a *)

   Alphabet[] //ToExpression [#, InputForm, Unevaluated] & // Map@Clear;

   (* a and all other letter symbols have been cleared *)
   ```
2. Generate a list of pairs `{someCharacter, f[indexOfCharacter]}`

   ```
   list = {ToExpression@Alphabet[], f /@ Range@26 } // Transpose
   ```

   > {{a, f[1]}, {b, f[2]}, {c, f[3]}, {d, f[4]}, {e, f[5]}, {f, f[6]}, {g,
   >   f[7]}, {h, f[8]}, {i, f[9]}, {j, f[10]}, {k, f[11]}, {l, 
   >   f[12]}, {m, f[13]}, {n, f[14]}, {o, f[15]}, {p, f[16]}, {q, 
   >   f[17]}, {r, f[18]}, {s, f[19]}, {t, f[20]}, {u, f[21]}, {v, 
   >   f[22]}, {w, f[23]}, {x, f[24]}, {y, f[25]}, {z, f[26]}}
3. Trying to `Apply` the `Set`(`=`) function via `Apply[Set, list, 1]` to the list of pair fails because `f` is both your "function" and a symbol in the list of letters.

   > $RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of f[6]. >>
4. The solution is to name your "function" something else like `func` that is not in your list of letters

   ```
   list = {ToExpression@Alphabet[], func /@ Range@26 } //Transpose;
   Apply[Set, list, 1];
   ```

After step **4** your symbols `a` through to `z` have been set to `func[someIndex]`. I hope you see that even in a toy example like this heavy use of mutable variables is asking for trouble.

A better way is to use for instance an `Association`

```
Alphabet[] //ToExpression [#, InputForm, Unevaluated] & // Map@Clear;    

letters = AssociationThread[ToExpression@Alphabet[], f /@ Range@26]
```

> <|a -> f[1], b -> f[2], c -> f[3], d -> f[4], e -> f[5], f -> f[6], 
>    g -> f[7], h -> f[8], i -> f[9], j -> f[10], k -> f[11], l -> f[12], 
>    m -> f[13], n -> f[14], o -> f[15], p -> f[16], q -> f[17], 
>    r -> f[18], s -> f[19], t -> f[20], u -> f[21], v -> f[22], 
>    w -> f[23], x -> f[24], y -> f[25], z -> f[26]|>

You can now call your letters via something like `letters[a]` which evaluates to `f[1]`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of `Evaluate` and `FromLetterNumber`

```
Evaluate[ToExpression[FromLetterNumber[Range[26]]]] = Array[func, 26]
```

Or, `Thread` is another option.

```
Thread[f1[ToExpression[FromLetterNumber[Range[26]]], Array[f2, 26]]] /. f1 -> Set
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help:

```
(* If your data are saved in an array... *)
f={1.2,2.2,3.1,4.3};

(* generate the letters and assign the values: *)
ToExpression[Table["a"<>ToString[i]<>"="<>ToString[f[[i]]],{i,1,Dimensions[f][[1]]}]];

{a1,a2,a3,a4}

Out[3]= {1.2, 2.2, 3.1, 4.3}
```

OR...

```
(* Generate Random data... *)
F = Table[RandomReal[{-3, 3}], {i, 1, 26}];

Clear[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, 
  v, w, x, y, z];
letters = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t,
    u, v, w, x, y, z};

Table[ToString[letters[[ii]]] <> "=" <> ToString[F[[ii]]], {ii, 1, 26}]
ToExpression[%]

a
b
```

This gives...

```
Out[4]={a=0.0177264,b=2.18909,c=1.36537,d=2.04752,e=2.43522,f=1.73921,g=-0.95031,h=-0.888718,i=-0.667,j=-1.88201,k=0.288534,l=2.11707,m=-0.893829,n=-1.1311,o=-2.61573,p=-1.11131,q=1.9456,r=-0.182795,s=2.705,t=-0.52068,u=-1.0116,v=0.339239,w=-2.40379,x=-2.88596,y=1.70749,z=-2.23369}

Out[5]={0.0177264,2.18909,1.36537,2.04752,2.43522,1.73921,-0.95031,-0.888718,-0.667,-1.88201,0.288534,2.11707,-0.893829,-1.1311,-2.61573,-1.11131,1.9456,-0.182795,2.705,-0.52068,-1.0116,0.339239,-2.40379,-2.88596,1.70749,-2.23369}

Out[6]=0.0177264

Out[7]=2.18909
```