# clear value from a bunch of symbols

Tags: symbols, clear

I have a bunch of symbols which are collected as a list inside a variable within a bit of code e.g.

```
a=1;b=2;
par={a,b};
```

I want to clear the values of both `a` and `b` using only a reference to `par`. Here is my attempt and the error produced:

```
Clear[Sequence@@par]
... Clear::ssym: Sequence@@par is not a symbol or a string.
```

I can understand why this gives an error but can't figure out a way out of it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `par` is simply `{1, 2}` here, how would it know about the symbols `a` and `b`?

Comment: To amplify Marius's comment, look at the result of `??par`.

Comment: I *do* get the idea. Is there a way, though ?

Comment: An approach similar to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/284) is one possibility: `par = Hold[a, b];` and much later, `Scan[Clear, par]` or `Clear @@ par`.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work. Because you used `Set`, not `SetDelayed`. After executing this code:

```
a = 1; 
b = 2; 

par = {a, b}
OwnValues[par]

(*
    {1, 2}
    {HoldPattern[par] :> {1, 2}}
*)
```

`par` isn't a list with `a` and `b`. `par` is a list that contains `{1, 2}`.

For your task you can use this code:

```
a = 1; 
b = 2; 

par := {a, b}
par
OwnValues[par]

(* 
    {1, 2}
    {HoldPattern[par] :> {a, b}} 
*)
```

Now you must take list of values from `OwnValues` rule:

```
Hold[par] /. OwnValues[par]

(* Hold[{a, b}] *)
```

And if you want clear `a` and `b`:

```
Hold[par] /. OwnValues[par] /. Hold[{args__}] :> Clear[args]

par
{a, b}

(* 
    {a, b} 
    {a, b}
*)
```

Definition for `par` preserved and for `a` and `b` cleared

Answer (score 0):

As others correctly pointed out, there is no way to establish variable names after the fact in this case. But if you have traced your code, which is a big if, of course, but imagine you did:

```
trace = Trace[
   a = 1; b = 2;
   par = {a, b}
];
```

Then you can fish out the variable names that were used during assignment and clear them:

```
Cases[
    trace,
    HoldPattern[par = vars : {___Symbol}] :> ClearAll @@ Unevaluated @ vars,
    All
];
```