# Replacing undefined variables

Tags: map, pure-function

Here's a MWE of what I want to do:

```
a = 1;
If[ValueQ[#], #, "Null"] & /@ {a, b, c}
(*Actual: {Null, Null, Null}*)
(*Expected: {1, Null, Null}*)
```

What am I not understanding about mapping pure functions? Or is my confusion elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a method similar to the one [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/284/50):

```
a = 1;
Reap[Scan[Function[Null, Sow[If[ValueQ[#], #, "Null"]], HoldFirst], 
          Hold[a, b, c]]][[-1, 1]]
   {1, "Null", "Null"}
```

Comment: ``System`Private`HasAnyCodesQ`` might be better if the OP cares about things with `*Values` other than `OwnValues`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear[a, b, c]

a = 1;

If[NumericQ[#], #, "Null"] & /@ {a, b, c}
```

> {1, "Null", "Null"}

Or more generally

```
a = {5, 5};

If[! SymbolQ[#], #, "Null"] & /@ {a, b, c}

{{5, 5}, "Null", "Null"}
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain why it doesn't work with `ValueQ`? I'd like to use it in cases where `a` might also be a list. So I basically want to return the variable in all cases except those in which it is undefined, and I'm not sure I can do that with `NumericQ`.

Comment: Just writing `{a, b, c}` already turns it into `{1, b, c}` when run.

Comment: I suppose I could use `If[NumericQ[#]||ListQ[#]...`

Comment: Please see updated andwer with `a` as a list

Answer (score 2):

You did say "replace" so here is a [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html) solution:

```
a = 1;

List @@ Replace[Hold[a, b, c], x_ /; ! ValueQ[x] :> "Null", {1}]
```

> ```
> {1, "Null", "Null"}
> ```

Other `Replace` methods, should you prefer one of them:

```
Replace[Unevaluated[{a, b, c}], x_ /; ! ValueQ[x] :> "Null", {1}]

List @@ Replace[Hold[a, b, c], {x_?ValueQ :> x, _ -> "Null"}, {1}]
```